# How to empty an javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [-3, -34, 1, 32, -100];
```

How can I remove all items and just leave an empty array?

And is it a good idea to use this?

```
arr = [];
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You answered your own question, at least the first one!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to empty an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 21):

If there are no other references to that array, then just create a new empty array over top of the old one:

```
array = [];
```

If you need to modify an existing array—if, for instance, there's a reference to that array stored elsewhere:

```
var array1 = [-3, -34, 1, 32, -100];
var array2 = array1;

// This.
array1.length = 0;

// Or this.
while (array1.length > 0) {
    array1.pop();
}

// Now both are empty.
assert(array2.length == 0);
```

Comment: This is the answer. I wrote pretty much the same before spotting that John had already done it.

Answer (score 4):

the simple, easy and safe way to do it is :

```
arr.length = 0;
```

making a new instance of array, redirects the reference to one another new instance, but didn't free old one.

Comment: `but didn't free old one.` - Perfect! Tx @a.boussema

Answer (score 3):

These are the ways to empty an array in JavaScript

1. `arr = [];`
2. `arr.splice(0, arr.length);`
3. `arr.length = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

one of those two:

```
var a = Array();
var a = [];
```

Comment: arr = [] is recommended as it takes up less space (code wise).

Comment: literally.  ::drum-roll rim-shot::

Answer (score 2):

Just as you say:

```
arr = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `arr = [];` to empty the array is far more efficient than doing something like looping and unsetting each key, or unsetting and then recreating the object.

Answer (score 0):

Out of box idea:

```
while(arr.length) arr.pop();
```

Comment: Will work, but is needlessly inefficient. `arr.length = 0` will be quicker and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Ways to clean/empty an array

1. This is perfect if you do not have any references from other places. (substitution with a new array)

> arr = []

2. This Would not free up the objects in this array and may have memory implications. (setting prop length to 0)

> arr.length = 0

3. Remove all elements from an array and actually clean the original array. (splicing the whole array)

> arr.splice(0,arr.length)