# Is JavaScript's array.clear() not a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to empty an array containing my drawn coordinates when a button "clear" is pressed.

When I call `drawnDivs.clear()`, I get an error that it is not a function. `drawnDivs` is certainly an array, and I have [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) `console.log`s printing things out. It's [hosted here](http://dylanstestserver.com/drawcss).

Comment: Out of interest, where did you get the idea to use clear()?  It doesn't appear to be a part of Javascript.

Comment: Ah looks like visual basic :)

Comment: a google search got me here: http://www.roseindia.net/java/javascript-array/javascript-array-clear.shtml

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Nope, it's not. But `drawnDivs.length = 0` should work.

Comment: This will work if it's a true array, and not just an array-like object.

Comment: @thomasrutter. True but it will preserve references and any other addition properties and functions defined on the array.

Comment: yes, this is still the best solution overall.  And to be honest, it would still work on array-like objects, it just wouldn't free any of the existing members from memory right away.  So only a minor point really.

Comment: @thomasrutter -an "arraylike" object, is not an Array, to begin with - so...(?!) .

Comment: Objects that can be used as if they are arrays but which aren't arrays are fairly common in JavaScript. If you want your array handing code to work with "real" arrays as well as objects which can act as arrays, then you have to make sure it can cope with the latter.

Answer (score 9):

drawnDivs = [];

Comment: Be careful, since this will not modify other references to the object.

Answer (score 4):

It was answered in Stack Overflow question *[How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript)*.

Two examples from the answer:

```
var A = ['some', 'values', 'here'];

//Method 1

//(This was my original answer to the question)

A = [];




// Method 2 (as suggested by Matthew Crumley)

A.length = 0
```

And [here is a nice write up](http://www.2ality.com/2012/12/clear-array.html) on these two methods by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer.

Comment: The chosen answer in the referred link is not the right solution as it does not clear the variables that refer to the array being cleared. The correct answer in that thread is http://stackoverflow.com/a/8134354/206687

Answer (score 2):

An optimized way to do it is:

```
while (arr.pop()) {}
```

See http://jsperf.com/kbk-clear-array/2.

Comment: This fails if the array has empty slots. This should do it:

`while (arr.length > 0) {
    arr.pop();
}`

Comment: **No, this should be:** ` while(arr.length){ arr.pop(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You could alternately use the Prototype library and then, use Prototype's `clear()` method.

Comment: Could be an alternative way, but i think there are a lot of easier ways without the use of libraries to clear an array.

Comment: Yea -- that would work, but it is using a sledgehammer to kill a fly.