# Multiple Polygons MySQL

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw several seperated Polygons (buildings) out of a database.
The data I get out of my database looks like this:

```
<buildings>
    <building build_id="94" build_gebaeude="A"
        build_geoX="49.26173942769648" build_geoY="7.350542675857582"
    />
    <building build_id="95" build_gebaeude="A"
        build_geoX="49.26173942769648" build_geoY="7.3524094933319475"
    />
    <building build_id="96" build_gebaeude="A"
        build_geoX="49.26019903253632" build_geoY="7.35234512031559"
    />
    <building build_id="97" build_gebaeude="A"
        build_geoX="49.26032506667364" build_geoY="7.350692879562416"
    />
    <building build_id="98" build_gebaeude="B"
        build_geoX="49.26155738350112" build_geoY="7.362129818801918"
    />
    <building build_id="99" build_gebaeude="B"
        build_geoX="49.26157138692462" build_geoY="7.364275586013832"
    />
    <building build_id="100" build_gebaeude="B"
        build_geoX="49.260255047748224" build_geoY="7.364361416702309"
    />
    <building build_id="101" build_gebaeude="B"
        build_geoX="49.260311062896506" build_geoY="7.362065445785561"
    />
</buildings>
```

The following code shows what I am doing to draw the buildings:

```
for (var i = 0; i < building.length-1; i++) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(building[i].getAttribute("build_geoX")),
        parseFloat(building[i].getAttribute("build_geoY"))
    );

    latlngbounds.extend(point);

    if( building[i].getAttribute("build_gebaeude") == 
        building[i+1].getAttribute("build_gebaeude") )
    {
        path.push(point);
    }
    else {
        path.push(point);
        poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: path,
            strokeWeight: 5,
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.30,
            strokeColor:'#FFFFFF',
            fillColor: '#a3141d'
        }); 
        polygons.push(poly);
        path.clear();
    }
}   
polygons[0].setMap(map);
polygons[1].setMap(map);
```

The problem is that not all points are drawn? I don´t understand where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be a problem with the `paths` array. It's not clear from the code you have included whether `paths` is a JavaScript `Array` or an array-like object, but since you are working with `paths` within the `for` loop and then attempting to clear the `paths` within the loop, I suggest:

- Create a new `paths` `Array` within the loop as it is needed
- Add code to manage the state of the array looping
- Change the code you use to check the building attributes and testing equality
- Since you are passing the paths array to the Polygon constructor, don't clear the array

---

```
var paths = null;
var aNewPathIsNeeded = true;
for ( var i = 0; i < building.length-1; i++) {
    //Create your point
    //Extend your bounds
    //Since you always add the point to the paths array, move it out of the if
    //check and perform some array state management:

    if ( aNewPathIsNeeded ) {
        paths = new Array( point );
        aNewPathIsNeeded = false;
    }
    else { paths.push( point ); }

    //Change the if condition to deal with just the specific case of interest:

    var currentBldgAttr = building[i].getAttribute("build_gebaeude");
    var nextBldgAttr = building[i+1].getAttribute("build_gebaeude");
    if ( !( currentBldgAttr === nextBldgAttr ) ) { //Change to use: '==='
        //Create your polygon
        //Add the polygon to the polygons array
        //New code to manage paths state:
        aNewPathIsNeeded = true;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, but I believe this code will help you move forward. As a side note, `clear()` is not a JavaScript `Array` method; when you want to empty an `Array`, use: `array.length = 0` as described in: [Is JavaScript's array.clear() not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020548/1314132)