# AngularJS not removing results within HTML

Tags: angularjs

Is there anyway to force angular to update/recompile the variables within a binding? I'm having an issue when I set my array (which is defined as a for loop within my HTML) equal to **[]** and it doesn't pick up on it. Any ideas?

Comment: angular triggers DOM updates in digest cycles so you could try to call Scope.$digest() - see <http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope> for more. Having said this, directly calling $digest is usually very bad idea so I guess that we are missing something in your app design. Could you please send a jsFiddle better illustrating your use case?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle demonstrating issue. That would help a lot.

Comment: If you are using an external library/plugin, Scope.$digest() could be your answer but if this is not the case then I wouldn't go there -- yet.

Comment: Perfect. $scope.$digest worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to make sure you work with the same array reference. I've been doing it like this whenever I want to update all of the elements to a bound array:

```
myArray.length = 0;
angular.forEach(newArray, function(item){
   myArray.push(item);
})

// Note: try without this line first as it isn't always necessary
$scope.$digest();
```

Using `myArray.length = 0` clears out the array retaining the reference to the array see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804235/difference-between-array-length-0-and-array) for more info.

You can also use the usual [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) and [unshift](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp) to remove and add items to the beginning of the array respectively.

Comment: Your answer is almost correct. Can you please just add "$scope.$digest();" as the last line and then I set your answer as accepted.

Comment: I've added the code with a disclaimer only because I've never had to use it (at least with an ng-repeat). Good to know guys in case I am having binding issues in the future!