# Javascript: Replace everything inside an Array with a new value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an Array:

```
var Arr = [1, 4, 8, 9];
```

At some point later in the code this happens:

```
Arr.push(someVar);
```

Here instead of pushing a new value, I want to replace the entire contents of `Arr` with `someVar`. (i.e. remove all previous contents so that if I console.logged() it I'd see that `Arr = [someVar]`

How could this be achieved??

Comment: did you try simply assigning the new value?? `Arr = [someVar]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Arr.length = 0;
Arr.push(someVar);
```

Read more: [Difference between Array.length = 0 and Array =[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804235/difference-between-array-length-0-and-array)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Arr = [somevar];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UbWTR/

Comment: ... that does not replace the contents but creates a new one :)

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the value just like this

```
var Arr = [1, 4, 8, 9]; //first assignment

Arr = [other value here]
```

It will replace array contents.

I hope it will help

Comment: This replaces the array with a value, not with a new array containing the value. (note - comment based on version without square brackets)

Answer (score 0):

you want splice to keep the same instance: `arr.splice(0, arr.length, someVar)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var Arr = [1, 4, 8, 9];  // initial array


Arr  = [] // will remove all the elements from array

Arr.push(someVar);  // Array with your new value
```