# Javascript: How to modify each element in array without changing the reference

Tags: javascript

```
let nestedArr = [[0,0],[0,0]]
let insideArr = nestedArr[0]
let targetArr = [1,1]
```

Basically I want to change the `insideArr's` elements to equal to `targetArr`, and it should change the first element of `nestedArr` too (because `insideArr` is refering to that).

```
insideArr = targetArr
insideArr = [..targetArr]
```

Above 2 approaches won't work because it will make `insideArr` pointing to new reference.
I know using `forEach` to loop through `insideArr` and assign it one by one should work, but is there a better way? And BTW, should I avoid this kind of usage?

Comment: `avoid this kind of usage` for what?

Comment: Why not `nestedArr[0] = targetArr`? Why do you need to maintain `insideArr` as a reference to `nestedArr[0]`?

Comment: Got to say the close votes are ridiculously over-zealous. It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Related: [Replace everything inside an Array with a new value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17945494/1048572), [Is there a better way to retain your array but efficiently concat or replace items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19672848/1048572)

Comment: @ksav That's what I'm asking, I don't if this kind of editing will make the code less robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must maintain `insideArr` as a reference to `nestedArr[0]`, you can use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to mutate `insideArr`

```js
let nestedArr = [[0,0],[0,0]]
let insideArr = nestedArr[0]
let targetArr = [1,1]

// Replace all of insideArr with targetArr
insideArr.splice(0, insideArr.length, ...targetArr)

console.log("still the same reference?", insideArr === nestedArr[0])
console.log("insideArr:", insideArr)
console.log("nestedArr:", nestedArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have good reasons for keeping the reference the same - and sometimes there are, you can do:

```
let nestedArr = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0]
];
let insideArr = nestedArr[0];
let targetArr = [1, 1];
insideArr.length = 0;
insideArr.unshift(...targetArr); // insideArr.push(...targetArr) works fine too
console.log(nestedArr);
```

Comment: I prefer Phil's one-line answer using splice, but keeping this here to show there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Love the old `.length = 0` trick. You could also use `push` instead of `unshift` (just because it's a more commonly understood method)

Comment: @Phil Honestly my first guess would've been that `unshift` adds them in the wrong order

Comment: @Bergi same. I had to check the docs ~ [_"if multiple elements are passed as parameters, they're inserted in chunk at the beginning of the object, in the exact same order they were passed as parameters"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

Comment: Good point re being less well known, and honestly I'm not sure why I chose it over push! Added comment to code.