# Difference between create a new Array and clear the length

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

If I have to delete all the items in an array, what's the difference between using `new Array` and `length = 0`? In the example, apparently the result looks the same.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) { 
    
    $scope.arrayData = ["1", "2", "3"];
    
    $scope.newArray1 = function(){
     $scope.arrayData = new Array();
    }    
    
    $scope.newArray2 = function(){
     $scope.arrayData = [];
    }
        
    $scope.lengthZero = function(){
     $scope.arrayData.length = 0;
    }    
            
    $scope.populate = function(){
     $scope.arrayData.push("1", "2", "3");
    }    
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Data:
</h2><br>
   <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in arrayData">{{data}}</li>
    </ul> 
    <button ng-click="newArray1()">New Array - 1st method</button>
    <button ng-click="newArray2()">New Array - 2nd method</button>
    <button ng-click="lengthZero()">Length = 0</button>
    
    <button ng-click="populate()">Populate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is quite a big difference between just using `[]` and `.length = 0`.

If you use `= []` you will assign a new reference to the variable, losing your reference to the original. By using `.length = 0` you will clear the original array, leaving the original reference intact.

Comment: As you said there is big difference between using `[]` and `.length = 0`. Can you come up with a practical scenario when this difference affect the result.

Answer (score 1):

With `array = new Array();` you will create a new reference.

A better way to clear an array and keep the reference would be:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

while (array.length) {
    array.pop();
}
```

Also take a look at this exact same question: [Difference between Array.length = 0 and Array =[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804235/difference-between-array-length-0-and-array)

Comment: This is not a better way. `.length = 0` would be the better way.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Why would that be better? Any reference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/1209018

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that this would work in every browser and is even faster. So you are right, better to use `.length = 0;`