# How to remove elements from Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to empty an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

How to remove all items from jQuery array?

I have array  `var myArray = [];`, I want to clear all items in this array on every post back.

Comment: That is not a `jQuery` array.

Comment: implied facepalm.  javascript is NOT jQuery....

Comment: looks like this array is already cleared :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simplest thing to do is just

```
myArray = [];
```

again.

*edit* — as pointed out in the comments, and in answers to other questions, another "simplest thing" is

```
myArray.length = 0;
```

and that has the advantage of retaining the same array object.

Comment: not enough jQuery.

Comment: well he could always call it `$myArray`

Comment: @jAndy I don't think that you need jQuery for everything.....

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs - It was a joke, most likely a reference to [this](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: This does NOT empty an array. This just assigns NEW empty array to that variable. `.length` solution works fine, while this does not in this use-case: `var obj = {arr: []}; var a = obj.arr; a.push('elem'); a.length = 0; console.log(obj);` vs `var obj = {arr: []}; var a = obj.arr; a.push('elem'); a = []; console.log(obj);`

Answer (score 10):

you can remove all item in myArray using array length, it's common pattern.

try this

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];    
myArray.length = 0; // remove all item
```

Answer (score 2):

To clear the array values you can do a simple:

```
myarray = [];
```

P.s.

```
jQuery != javascript
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a jQuery array, that's just a javascript array. When a page posts back, it re-renders and all of the javascript is re-run, you don't need to clear the contents of the array.

if, during execution of the page, you wanted to clear a javascript array, just re-initialize it as a new, blank array:

```
myArray = []; // no var, we are just initializing not declaring
```