# How to clear the jsonArray in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to empty an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

```
var jsonParent = [];
```

This is my jsonArray I am pushing some elements in the array, but now I want to empty this array and remove all elements from it.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of saving memory and references use

```
jsonParent.length = 0
```

Comment: Nothing hacky =) it's javascript

Answer (score 3):

If there are no other references to the same array then the easiest thing to do is just assign `jsonParent` to a new empty array:

```
jsonParent = [];
```

But if your code has other references to the same array instance then that would leave those other references with the original (populated) array and `jsonParent` with a different (empty) array. So if that is possible in your situation and you want to empty the actual array instance that you already have you can do:

```
jsonParent.length = 0;
// or if you like ugly:
jsonParent.splice(0, jsonParent.length);
```

(Note also that you are not using JSON here in any way. It's not JSON if it's not a string.)

Answer (score 1):

just assign

```
jsonParent = []
```

again when you want to remove all elements