# What is the most efficient way to empty a plain object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, dictionary

As stated [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript), It seems that the most efficient way to empty an existing array (and NOT to allocate a new one) in javascript is to use:

```
array.length = 0;
```

Does the same operation work for plain objects? (aka "associative arrays" or "dictionaries")
If not, what is the most efficient way to **empty** an existing javascript object?

I think that allocating a new one is not the best option, since it will push some extra work to the garbage collector, and will allocate some new memory on the heap, but I might be wrong.

I need a solution that works at least with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Doesn't look like .length = 0 works for associative arrays (http://jsfiddle.net/7XVym/).

Comment: JS doesn't have associative arrays. Do you mean objects?

Comment: Can't you simply do `array = null;`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The shortest way to do that is to create a new object.  You'd end up garbage collecting all the properties anyway.

```
var foo = {
    a: 5,
    b: 4
};
foo = {};
```

You could also iterate over the properties and remove them individually:

```
for (var prop in foo) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        delete foo[prop];
    }
}
```

It's also worth pointing out, as a matter of verbiage, that JavaScript has *objects* with *properties*, not associative arrays.

Comment: It should be noted that `foo = {}` creates a new object and **leaves the original object as is**. This makes a difference when there are other references to the original object: `var foo = {a:5,b:4}; var bar = foo; foo = {};`
At the end, `bar`is still `{a:5,b4}` and **not** `{}` as one might expect.

Comment: @Ignitor How avoid that and propagate the change to bar too?

Comment: @Dario I guess you have to remove the properties individually using `delete` as stated in the answer.

Comment: Yes i do that with a for that cycle all elements and delete it