# correctly resetting a global variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, scope

so, in ***[this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript)*** people are discussing the fact that

```
A = [1,2,3];
```

and then doing

```
A = [];
```

will not reset the array but create a new one.

***My question is***, if I use a global object variable

```
myglobals = { A : [] }
```

Can I safely reset the array with

```
myglobals.A = [];
```

Right? Since that's referencing the same object property and thus I'm not actually creating a new array, am I?

**Update to question due to remarks below**

Since there is a general consensus that `splice(0)` is the way to go, and since a very similar question has an answer that explains the impact to browser freeing up memory, I'm wondering if it's generally safe and proper to set any defined object (whether array or function or string, etc...) to `null` in order to reset it's *value* while retaining it's *reference*?

Comment: an object could still have its prototype, and it must! thats what javascript is. objects of prototypes, empty or not! because even `null` is something, it is nothing, so also `[]` is something, but `var A=undefined` is undefined, but A as object of some proto/type exist!

Comment: @alex23, thanks for referring to that other post. It seems that `myglobals.A.splice(0)` is actually not really the best way. From the accepted answer there, I glean that it should be set to `null` in order to allow the browser to collect the memory, right?

Comment: @codelio, perhaps I am not asking my question well, sorry about that if it's the case. Your answer below doesn't sound right: if I set `A=undefined`, then `typeof(A)` returns `undefined` but I expect to get `object`

Comment: `null` is not preparing `A` to free its taken memory, because its null. have look at `var A=1; A=void(A)`, thats what you mean perhaps, but it's still valid A, the same as `var A` is in this moment. javascript frees memory if the objects/value 's parent is set so that it does not have anymore that child.

Comment: `console.log(a.constructor.name, typeof a);` //"Array", "object"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a new array. If you want to truncate the array, just set its length to zero:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a.length = 0;
// a is now []
```

In your example with object properties, it's just the same. There are no pointers in JavaScript, just reference values. So the value of `myglobals.A` is a reference to an array. When you assign a new array to it, that value becomes a new reference, to a different array.

Comment: To clear an array, you need to remove all the elements on the object (setting `arr.length = 0` won't actually remove the references from the array), a concise way of reasonably clearing the array is: `arr.splice(0)`.

Comment: @zzzzBov Are you sure? Because `var a = [1,2,3]; a.length = 0; a[1]; // undefined`.

Comment: `arr.splice(0)` affects the current array reference (maybe you were thinking `arr.slice` which is similar), but it appears that you're right about `a.length = 0` clearing out the array items. I was under the impression that it merely masked the existence of properties on the array instance.

Comment: so if it's supposed to be `myglobals.A.splice(0)`, how would I do it if my variable is an object? Do I `myglobals.A=undefined`? as suggested below?

Comment: @tim Yes, setting it to undefined or null work, for any type of value. We all thought your question was specifically about arrays.

Comment: @zzzzBov Yup, I read "splice" and thought "slice", then realized the mistake. About setting length to zero, the spec includes a special internal method on arrays to deal with length changes, see http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.5.1

Comment: @tim Regarding your update: an object will be eligible for garbage collection once there is no reference to it anymore. So, considering `myglobals = { A : [] }`, setting `myglobals.A = null` will allow memory to be freed only if there are no further references to that array (for example, if you previously stated that `var b = myglobals.A`, that would have been a second reference to the same array, and you'd have to nullify it too).

Comment: @codelio See my latest comment right above. The question seemed like being about how to empty an array; 2 hours later, it was updated and now looks like it's about memory management.

Comment: var b = is not a reference, it is a new variable in its scope so it has its own memory space with derived value of myglobals.A, but if ..A is set to null, B wil be null too if this is set after A. sure! :)

Comment: @codelio If `var a = {}, b = a`, then both variables hold references to the same object, and the memory used by that object cannot be freed until both references are destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this still creates a new array.  The important factor is the assignment, not the scope to which the "A" variable is attached.  As long as you do something that looks like `something = []`, the JavaScript engine is going to manufacture a new Array object (the `[]` part) then assign a reference to it to `something`.

Answer (score 2):

Not really...

```
// make a global variable
var a = [1,2,3];

// Assign it to something
var someObj = { value: a };
someObj.value; // [1,2,3];

// set a new value for the global
a = [];
a; // []
someObj.value; // [1,2,3];
```

This is the initial code you mention.  You can change the object the global variable points to, but you can't change other reference to the object you are replacing.

And the same problem exists with your second example:

```
// make a global variable
var globals = { a: [1,2,3] };

// Assign it to something
var someObj = { value: globals.a };
someObj.value; // [1,2,3];

// set a new value for the global
globals.a = [];
globals.a; // []
someObj.value; // [1,2,3];
```

You would have to reference the `globals` container object if you want references to be updated.  That is other object hold a reference to the container, and then you can change the contents of that container.

```
// make a global variable
var globals = { a: [1,2,3] };

// assign a reference to the container in another object.
var someObj = { globals: globals };
someObj.globals.a; // [1,2,3];

// set a new value for the global
globals.a = [];
globals.a; // []
someObj.globals.a; // [];
```

Thought that can get a bit unwieldy.

---

You could also alter the object reference by the global, rather than replacing it.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a; // a and b now reference the same object.

a.splice(0); // remove all items from this array, without replace the array object.
a; // [];
b; // [];
// a and b now still point to the same array, which is now empty.
```

Comment: I think it should be `a.splice(0)` at the end there.

Answer (score 1):

```
var A=[1,2,3];
A=undefined;
console.log(A); //undefined
```

Comment: well, that's just changing the array to nothing now, not resetting it as a variable of type `array`. I guess this way I could do two statements: `A=undefined;A=[];` but does that definitely remove the A assignment or does it also just add a new reference? How about `A=null`?

Comment: well any override of a variable will work. A.length=0 will not work anytime, depends of the type of A. in other words what kind of prototype it is made from. but overriding with low level types will allways empty everything in it, specially when changing types with it, what `null` and `undefined` do!

Comment: with other words, once a variable is given, it has a scope! somewhere it belongs to. but if this what it belongs to is changed or overwritten, javascript free's the space with the new thing.. it is like writing `var A` which is something but not nothing, it is undefined!

Answer (score 1):

```
var handle={};
handle.A=[1,2,3,4,5,{x:2,y:3}];
console.log(handle);
```

[image: what is given now]

```
delete handle.A;
console.log(handle); //A is gone!
```

[image: after deleting A from handle]

why is delete sometime better? it really kills `A` from `handle`, following could confuse you in working with larger objects, if you hope `.length` is telling you the truth.

```
handle.A=[null];
handle.B=undefined;
handle.C=null;
handle.A.length=10;
console.log(handle, handle.length, handle.A.length);
```

not very save in coding, because i set it `=10` and
your script could assume wrong there is something to loop thru 10 elements.
so `handle.A=null` will help, but not really changing the structure of your object.
but it can also not break your script because you have something like `var A`, and you could prevent loops thru not existing elements with it. same works with set to `undefined`, se below..

[image: so be carefull]

Comment: in this kind of typing you really free memory for A