# Javascript- is there a way to destroy all elements of an array by one command?

Tags: javascript

my script creates an empty array and then fill it. But if new arguments come then script is expected to destroy old one and create new one.

```
var Passengers = new Array();

function FillPassengers(count){
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
        Passengers[i] = i;
}
```

I wanna destroy the old one because new count may be less than old one and last elements of array still will store old array? is that right and if it is how can I destroy it?

Comment: This post will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: this post will help you.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 11):

This will create a new empty array `Passengers = []`.
Not sure about what you should do.

Or just `Passengers.length = 0;`

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do this to empty an array (without changing the array object itself):

```
Passengers.length = 0;
```

Or, with your code:

```
function FillPassengers(count){
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
        Passengers[i] = i;
    Passengers.length = count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Very Simple

```
riz = [];
```

or

```
riz.length = 0;
```

Comment: Too late for the party...

Answer (score 2):

You can just re-assign a new *Array* instance

```
Passengers = [ ];
```

respectively

```
Passengers = new Array();
```

The garbage collector till take care of the rest.

Comment: thanks a lot. Passengers = [ ]; Passengers = new Array();
both solves the problem

Comment: Yeah... only both applied solves it `:D` @jAndy You see how multiple alternatives can help the OP to understand the things? `:)`

Comment: :) each one is ok thanks again