# Is it good practice to release array's memory by setting it's length to zero?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

For example:

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5];
test.length = 0;
```

Is this a good way to release memory of variable `test`?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but it you could do `var test = [1,2,3]` and then `test = []`

Comment: Use delete test instead of that

Comment: @Deepu `delete` does not work on variables. This post may be of interest to you: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: Yes, this will clear the array and all references to it. It's preferable to test = [] as that will create a new array, and may not replace all references to the original array.

Comment: Also, this may be worth a read:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

No don't worry about that, that just makes your code longer. Keep your variable in the tightest of scope, and if not needed anymore, it should get handled by the garbage collection system.