# Removing all items from Kendo UI MVVM ObservableArray

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

What is the recommended method for removing all items from a Kendo UI MVVM ObservableArray?

First, I tried re-initializing the ObservableArray, but that caused problems in my app. Next, I tried setting the length of the ObservableArray to 0, but that also caused problems. Then, I put the pop() method in a while loop. So far, that seems to be working, but I'm wondering if that's the recommended method.

Comment: Assuming Kendo ObservableArray is similar to a standard JS array, then see: [How to empty an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1232040/9664)

Answer (score 5):

**Update 23/01/2016** - patriks (answer below mine) has discovered a `.empty()` method which appears to be undocumented which does what I have used as an inbuilt method:

```
console.log(searchResults.empty); //function(){this.splice(0,this.length)}
```

I would recommend using this approach instead.

**Old answer:**

Just had to solve this today, I got it working with this:

```
var searchResults = new kendo.data.ObservableArray(['A', 'B', 'C']);
...
searchResults.splice(0, searchResults.length); //empties array.
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/wJW6f/

Comment: empty() didn't work for me. I'd advise sticking to the documented splice method.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to stumble upon this old thread and just thought I'd add that there is an (undocumented?) `empty()` method for ObservableArrays that does the splicing for you.

Updated Kyles fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wJW6f/2/