# Define component list dynamically for Sidekick and Insert dialog in CQ5

Tags: extjs, event-handling, aem

I am trying to modify the list of components displayed in the sidekick based on the user's privileges.
I am trying it as explained [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/HowToDefineComponentListDynamically.html).

What i would like to know is how to send back the modified **allowed** array that is received as the argument, because what ever modifications i make to the array appears to be in the local scope. For e.g. if i want the allowed components to consist only of the default list component, i do something like this.

```
function MyHandler(cell, allowed, componentList) {
    allowed = [];
    allowed.push("/libs/foundation/components/list");
}
```

But once the control goes back to the function that triggered this event, these changes are not visible. Should i be returning the array or something ? Could you please explain if i am missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Finally figured the issue. I wanted to clear the existing list of components that were passed on to my handler, for which I used `allowed = [];`.

This removed all the existing references to the allowed array. (More about this explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234337/1201244)).

Thus changing it to `allowed.length = 0;` works absolutely fine.

```
function MyHandler(cell, allowed, componentList) {
    allowed.length = 0;
    allowed.push("/libs/foundation/components/list");
}
```