# Way to empty an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I read the topic [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript/1234337#1234337)

Answer :

> Very simple:
>
> A = [];

I am interested in the comment by Daniel Baulig:

> this will NOT empty the array, but create a new, empty array. This
>   might cause problems, especially if there are other references to the
>   array. OP: Please consider to accept Matthew's answer instead. It is
>   the cleaner and formally correct approach. –  Daniel Baulig Jan 19 '11
>   at 13:08

Can you tell me what problems this could cause?

Comment: The answer/comment clearly mentions the problems.

Comment: Here are some methods to clear an array http://jsperf.com/array-destroy/40

Comment: Rather than put a minus question you would have tried to understand the question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you may have another reference to that array.

Consider this :

```
var A = ['A'];
var B = A;
```

If you do

```
A = [];
```

this will still let B be `['A']`. That's the difference between emptying (or changing) an array, or replacing it (what you did).

When you do

```
A.length=0;
```

then B will be empty too.