# Changing the size of an array in Javascript or node.js efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

In my node.js code, there is a buffer array to which I store the contents of a received image, every time an image being received via TCP connection between the node.js as TCP client and another TCP server:

```
var byBMP = new Buffer (imageSize);
```

However 
the size of image,imageSize, differs every time which makes the size of byBMP change accordingly. That means something like this happen constantly:

```
 var byBMP = new Buffer (10000);
.... wait to receive another image
 byBMP = new Buffer (30000);
.... wait to receive another image
 byBMP = new Buffer (10000);
... etc
```

Question:

Is there any more efficient way of resizing the array byBMP. I looked into this: [How to empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript) which gave me some ideas ebout the efficient way of emptying an array, however for resizing it I need you guys' comments.node.js

Comment: Do you know if you actually have a problem here?  Have you measured to see if this is actually an inefficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficient way would be to use Streams rather than a buffer. The buffer will keep the content of the image in your memory which is not very scalable.

Instead, simply pipe the download stream directly to a file output:

```
imgDownloadStream.pipe( fs.createWriteStream('tmp-img') );
```

If you're keeping the img in memory to perform transformation, then simply apply the transformation on the stream buffers parts as they pass through.