# Javascript array reset not giving desired output

Tags: javascript, arrays

I used the method described here:

[How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

to reset an array in my code.

My code is such

```
var check = new Array();
var i = 0;

if(some statements){
    check[i]=something;
    i=+1;
}

function reset(){
    check.length=0;
}
```

After executing of if statement, if I `console.log()`, the array is displayed as such

`["abc","def","ghi"]`. Then the reset function is called.

After that, the next time the array is used, it logs as follows:

`[1: "abc", 2: "def", ...]`

What can I do to make it reset to original empty array?

Comment: What's wrong with `arr.push()`?

Comment: I think it's `i+=1;` too. I don't think you can have it round the other way.

Comment: The answer is in the question you linked...

Comment: No repro: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3S9T3/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to empty an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your whole code using:

```
var check = [];

if(some statements)
{
    check.push(something);
}

function reset()
{
    check = [];
}
```

It may be better to refactor your code though. `check` may be out of scope inside the function, so you should try:

```
var check = [];

if(some statements)
{
    check.push(something);
}

function reset()
{
    return [];
}

check = reset();
```

Comment: While `check = []` will definitely *clear* the array, it does so by creating an entirely new array; if there are any references to the original one, this will break them...

Comment: The problem seems to be that `check.length = 0;` is apparently not working for the OP (when it should), but you haven't explained why.

Comment: Exactly. Nevertheless, I fixed it by resetting the variable `i`.

Comment: But you don't need to use the `i` variable at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function reset() {
  check.splice(0, check.length);
}
```

Comment: this will retain the same array, only the elements will be discared