# Blueimp File Upload: file is not deleting correctly from queue

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am having following blueimp file upload code:

```
.on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
   data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#FilesListThumb');
   $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
         var node = $("<div><h6 fileId="+index+">X</h6></div>").addClass("thumbnail-ib");
         node.appendTo(data.context);
         node.find("h6").click(function(){
              data.files.splice($(this).attr("fileId"),1);
              node.remove();
         });
 });
```

When i click `h6` sometimes it removes files from queue sometimes not.Why? Next question is how to remove all files from queue?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use an incremented global variable instead of the index value:

```
var globalVariable = 0; // To be declare in a global context

.on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#FilesListThumb');
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        globalVariable = globalVariable + 1;
        var node = $("<div><h6 fileId=" + globalVariable + ">X</h6></div>").addClass("thumbnail-ib");
        file.fileId = globalVariable; // Add the same id to the file
        node.appendTo(data.context);
        node.find("h6").click(function(){
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                if(file.fileId == $(this).attr("fileId"){
                     data.files.splice(index, 1);
                     return false; // Break the loop
            };
            node.remove();
        });
    });
});
```

To remove files from the queue you can look at the following question on SO (I like the tanguy_k's answer) : [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript) and apply it to the `data.files` array.

Comment: I am using something like `                    node.find("h6").on("click",function(){
                        for(var i=0;i<data.files.length;i++){
                            if(data.files[i].name==$(this).attr("fileName")){
                                data.files.splice(i,1);
                                node.remove();
                            }
                        }                                
                    }); ` and its working correct. Is it good?

Comment: @Manish It assumes that all your file have different name.

Comment: No it may be same file name

Comment: So you should use an other id without collision, like an autoincremented-id, or an hashed combined value (name + timestamp). My example above is with an auto-incremented value.