# How to get array length without length property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Even though we can use `array.length` to get array length it may go wrong in a case like below..

```js
var a = [2, 4, "bang", undefined, NaN, 5]; 
a.length = 0; 
document.write(a.length);
```

counting with `for in` may also go wrong if the array has additional properties defined.

So is there a way to get array length dynamically?

Comment: Don't do `a.length = 0;`?

Comment: Not sure this really deserves the downvotes, is it not a reasonable (if a tad simple) question?

Comment: I'm reading again and again and I couldn't find the logic behind your `a.length = 0`!!!

Comment: I didn't know `array.length = 0` changes the true array length. sorry.. @LcSalazar

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but worth reading: [*Empty an array in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/empty-an-array-in-javascript/1234337#1234337).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling

```
a.length = 0;
```

Does remove all elements from the array

```
console.log(a[2]) // undefined
```

Therefore, your array no longer contains any elements.

Also remember that setting properties that are not coercible to an integer (`a.something = 'blah'`) will not affect the length property.

Answer (score 1):

If you do, `a.length = 0`, It will remove all array elements, and the length will be 0. Does it show any other value?

Answer (score 1):

`a.length` is always correct. `a.length = 0;` TRUNCATES all data from array.