# Javascript, How to send a placeholder variable to a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have a function with an if-statement. When this if-statement is triggered I want to tell another function to clear out its array.

```
function firstFunction(){
    if(!$myCheckBox.is(':checked')){
        secondFunction(myArray.length = 0);
    }
}

function secondFunction(myArray){
    if(myArray.length == 0){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean pass in an empty array? `renderResults([]);`

Comment: Just send 0 as an argument. if you need `results` array also inside the function then send it too.. llike in the following `renderResults(0,results)`

Comment: Simply sending 0 to the array wont work, as it does not clear out the array. And sending [] will just create a new array right? Well, I want the same array to remain, but I want to clear it of any rows within.

Comment: [How to clear an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-to-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: That is where I got results.length = 0 from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *renderResult* function expects the placeholder variable. You shall send it like this:

```
$('#randomName').change(function() {
if(!$randomName.is(':checked')){
            // modify [results] if needed, e.g. results.length = 0;
            renderResults(results);
```

Comment: Please do not use code snippets for code not intended to actually run without extra context. Clicking run here just produce a syntax error. You can just use a code block without the run button instead. Thanks!