# On change delete everything in array and add new values in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have function, which on change calling method 'saveSelectedValue'.

```
  this.$filtercat.on('change', { that : this }, this.saveSelectedValue);
```

This method does only one thing: saving data in array.

```
  saveSelectedValue : function (e) {
    var that = e.data.that,
    selectArray = that.filterSelectedCategories;
    selectArray.push($('.posts-filter-cat').val());
    console.log(selectArray); //every time gives me extended array  
},
```

Now I am adding new value to the existing array. But I want to delete everything and add new value in array on every change.

Comment: See this answer for every possible method http://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/4543256

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear array before pushing new value. Easy way to remove all exisiting values is to set length to `0`:

```
saveSelectedValue : function (e) {
    var that = e.data.that,
    selectArray = that.filterSelectedCategories;
    selectArray.length = 0; // clear selectArray array
    selectArray.push($('.posts-filter-cat').val());
    console.log(selectArray);
},
```

Comment: Couldn't most of that be compressed to: `that.filterSelectedCategories; = [$('.posts-filter-cat').val()]`?

Comment: @Cerbrus  Maybe, but then it will overwrite filterSelectedCategories array and reference will be broken. Not sure what framework OP's using, but it may cause problems.

Comment: It could be the same thing, if I know that I have only 1 item in array. selectArray.splice(0,1); Right?

Comment: @max: You don't even have to know there's only one item: `selectArray.splice(0, selectArray.length, $('.posts-filter-cat').val());`