# Unable to clear the array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove all the elements of the array using `array = [];` when the div value becomes 'clear all' but the array is not able to clear.
All i am doing here is including the selected checkbox value in the div called 'filtervalue'.

here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.filtercheck, #location, #sorting , #filtervalue').on('click', function(e) {
      var parameter = [];
      var filter = [];
      var index = "";
      var HTML = "";
      var newHTML = "";

      $(".filtercheck").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          filter.push($(this).val())
          parameter.push(this.name + "=" + $(this).val());
        }
      });

      if ($("#location").val()) {
        parameter.push($("#location").val());
      }

      if ($('#sorting').val()) {
        parameter.push($('#sorting').val());
      }


      for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
        HTML = HTML + '<div>' + filter[i] + '</div>';
      }

      newHTML = HTML + '<div>' + 'Clear All' + '</div>'
      $('#filtervalue').html(newHTML).show();

      if (filter.length == 0) {
        $('#filtervalue').hide();
      }


      $('div#filtervalue>div').each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function() {
          text = ($(this).text());

          if (text == 'Clear All') {
            filter = [];
            console.log(filter.length)
            parameter = [];
            console.log(parameter.length)
            $('#filtervalue').hide();
          } else {
            filter = jQuery.grep(filter, function(n) {
              return n != text;
            });

            console.log(filter)
            console.log(parameter)

            checkbox = $(":checkbox[value=" + text + "]")

            if (checkbox.prop("checked", true)) {
              checkbox.prop("checked", false);
              $(this).remove();
            }
          }
        });

      });

      parameter = parameter.join('&');
      $('#loading-image').show();
      console.log(filter)
      console.log(parameter)

      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}',
        type: 'GET',
        data: parameter,
        success: function(data) {
          var a = $(data).find('.prodthumb');
          $('.productgrid').html(a);
          $("img.lazy").lazyload();
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        },

        complete: function() {
          $('#loading-image').hide();
        }
      });

    });
</script>
```

How can i remove all the elements of the array?
Thank you

Comment: `How can i remove all the elements of the array?` if the array is called `array`, you can simply write `array = [];`, or even `array = null` (but then if you want to use array functions on array, you need to make it an array again)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I have a feeling it is a logic error since you seem to be setting it to `filter = []`. Too much code for me to go through this early in the morning.

Comment: if filter = [] is not working, then it may be possible that it is not entering the if loop. Have you checked if the text value is actually 'Clear All' and is it entering the if loop?

Comment: I am able to enter the loop

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below code. just move your variable declaration at top like below.

```
var parameter = [];
    var filter = [];
    var index = "";
    var HTML = "";
    var newHTML = "";

    $('.filtercheck, #location, #sorting , #filtervalue').on('click', function(e) {   

      $(".filtercheck").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          filter.push($(this).val())
          parameter.push(this.name + "=" + $(this).val());
        }
      });

      if ($("#location").val()) {
        parameter.push($("#location").val());
      }

      if ($('#sorting').val()) {
        parameter.push($('#sorting').val());
      }


      for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
        HTML = HTML + '<div>' + filter[i] + '</div>';
      }

      newHTML = HTML + '<div>' + 'Clear All' + '</div>'
      $('#filtervalue').html(newHTML).show();

      if (filter.length == 0) {
        $('#filtervalue').hide();
      }


      $('div#filtervalue>div').each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function() {
          text = ($(this).text());

          if (text == 'Clear All') {
            filter = [];
            console.log(filter.length)
            parameter = [];
            console.log(parameter.length)
            $('#filtervalue').hide();
          } else {
            filter = jQuery.grep(filter, function(n) {
              return n != text;
            });

            console.log(filter)
            console.log(parameter)

            checkbox = $(":checkbox[value=" + text + "]")

            if (checkbox.prop("checked", true)) {
              checkbox.prop("checked", false);
              $(this).remove();
            }
          }
        });

      });

      parameter = parameter.join('&');
      $('#loading-image').show();
      console.log(filter)
      console.log(parameter)

      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}',
        type: 'GET',
        data: parameter,
        success: function(data) {
          var a = $(data).find('.prodthumb');
          $('.productgrid').html(a);
          $("img.lazy").lazyload();
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        },

        complete: function() {
          $('#loading-image').hide();
        }
      });

    });
```

Comment: No effect it still behaves the same