# Selection on selectbox in IE when modifying the options with angular

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, select

I'm developping an application that use Angular and we want to synchronize two selectbox (HTML). It means when I click a value in the first selectbox , I want value in the second selectbox updated, and clickable too.

I did the following plunker to explain our problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/KkBVcu29CZ6Elr741ZPe?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
'use strict';
angular.module("myApp", []).run(function($rootScope) {}).config(function () {});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl',  function(
        $scope) {
    //$scope.obj2Selected = null;
    $scope.list1 = [];
    $scope.list1.push({
                id : "1",
                name : "1", 
                selected : false
            });
    $scope.list1.push({
                id : "2",
                name : "2", 
                selected : false
            });
    $scope.list1.push({
                id : "3",
                name : "3", 
                selected : false
            });

    $scope.list2 = [];
    $scope.list2 .push({
                id : "1",
                name : "1" 
            });
    $scope.list2.push({
                id : "2",
                name : "2"
            });
    $scope.list2.push({
                id : "3",
                name : "3" 
            });   

    $scope.selectionObjDone = function(){
        $scope.obj2Selected = null; 
        $scope.list2.length = 0;
      $scope.list2.push({
            id : Math.random().toString(),
            name : Math.random().toString()
        });
      $scope.list2.push({
            id : Math.random().toString(),
            name : Math.random().toString()
        });
    };
});
</script>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select size="10" id="listNodes" style="width:200px;"
    ng-options="obj as obj.name for obj in list1 track by obj.id" ng-model="objSelected"
    ng-change="selectionObjDone()">
</select>
<select size="10" style="width:200px;" id="select2"
    ng-options="obj as obj.name for obj in list2 track by obj.id"
    ng-model="obj2Selected" >
</select>

</div>
</html>
```

In this plunker everything looks fine. But if you copy/paste the exact same code in a test.html for example, opening it in IE (V11), you'll see the problem:
Start by clicking on the first selectbox to choose an option or another.
Try to select then an option in the second selectbox, you'll see that the selection is no more possible.

It works well in FF or Chrome, and also it works better on Plunker, even if sometimes it stops to work in Plunker (I did not find the exact use case).

It has a real link to the fact that I empty the array that is used to fill the 2nd selectbox. If I comment this line, everything work fine:
$scope.list2.length = 0;

I tried different ways to empty this array:
[How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Does anybody have an idea on what happens here and how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, even with an expert of Angular we did not find the answer, but waiting a few, the new version of Angular (1.5.7) resolved by magic the problem!