# Remove multiple controls from ControlArray

Tags: angular

I have a ControlArray and at some point I need to remove multiple items from it , or easier , just clear/empty the whole array.

This is the current array :

```
       let myControls = new ControlArray([]);
       // Add some items to this array : 

          for(let i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
                myControls.push({
                    firstName : new Control( '' , Validators.required ) ,
                    lastName  : new Control( '' , Validators.required ) ,
                })
           }

       // After this my controlArray has 5 controls and 
       //everything works in the view properly .
```

Now I have a button that has a (click) event bind to it and I want to clear ( remove all the controls ) from myControls , but I can't find the solution.

In the documentations , there is a *myControl.**removeAt(index)***  function which removes only one item , but there is not any function that removes all the items.

Also , I've tried this :

```
          for(let i = 0 ; i<myControls.length ; i++){
                myControls.removeAt(i);
           }
```

But obviously this wont work because every time you remove an item from the array , the index will change !!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `ControlArray` seems to have a `public controls: AbstractControl[]` property. Looking at the code, the `ControlArray`-specific methods are using this array directly. I suppose then it is legal and endorsed to do `myControls.controls = []` or `myControls.controls.length = 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't checked if there is a better solution but this should work as well:

```
while(myControl.length) {
  myControls.removeAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Looks extremely hacky though .:) , I wish Angular team would have thought about this.

Comment: You can try one of those http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript I don't actively use JS or TS myself (only Dart)

Comment: actually none of them is related to this , because all of those are touching the array itself , but in here , myControl is not an array and has a special function called removeAt() . The array is living inside in controls.
But again , so far your answer is the best way unless Angular team adds a removeAll() function to that element.
Thanks again.

Comment: You are right https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/60727c4d2ba1e4b0b9455c767d0ef152bcedc7c2/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/model.ts#L452

Comment: Most elegant and efficient way I've found, Gunter you're my saver once again :D

Answer (score 10):

not much related angular, but normally when you are splicing an array in a loop you want to go backward with your counter, so that the next index `i--` would still refer to the original element in the array

```
for(var i=myControls.length;i-->0;){
    myControls.removeAt(i);
}
```