# Reset JS array and set dynamic key array with one line of code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**EDIT**

The following question [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript) does not answer the question i.e. I get how to set / reset an array but that was not my question. I want to to do is:

1. set the key with a dynamic value e.g. UUID and,
2. then set element[0] (the above) to true in one line of code.

**QUESTION**

Code base: Angular 1.5x, lodash 4.x

Seems like a basic question but cannot find an answer. Is it possible using JS, Angular or lodash to reset an array and set it at the same time per the example below. As per the example below the array will keep pushing unless I set reset it. Why you ask, example if I'm using a UUID as key in the HTML e.g.

**HTML**

```
<li id="{[{contactus.app_id}]}"
    ng-show="view.state[item.uuid]"
    ng-repeat="item in collection.items track by item.uuid">
</li>
```

**JS (Angular)**

NOTE: this code works and I could also use replace `$scope.view.state.length = 0;` with `$scope.view.state = [];` but my question is more along the lines of reseting an array, adding a dynamic key and setting it to true all in one line of code. The complexity is in the dynamic key.

```
$scope.view = {state:[]};

$scope.setViewState = function (id) {
    // how can I collapse the following 2 lines of code into one
    $scope.view.state = [];
    $scope.view.state[id] = true;
};
```

Comment: Is `id` a string or a number?  (Because if it's a non-numeric string setting length to 0 isn't doing what you think it's doing).

Comment: A string - on the backend I add a alpha prefix to uuid and dehydrate of hyphens. The code above works, I'm wondering how to get it into 1 line of code.

Comment: You'll want to change from an array `[]` to an object `{}` - then you can make your re-assignment into `$scope.view.state = {[id] = true};` using a computed property.  (But if you need to support older browsers then you'll need to use two lines for now.)

Comment: sean, cannot set {[id] = true} as I get js:45 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = ...  that is the problem as you need to set a dynamic key with a array[dynamicProperty] and cannot set dynamic key inside of object

Comment: You *can* but only in latest Chrome and Firefox - *and* any build tools you are using have to support the syntax as well.

Comment: "above mentioned"? We don't see the same messages as you do, above the question...

Comment: Why do you care how many lines a piece of code takes? I'd take a readable, maintainable 2 lines of code over an obscure one-liner any day...

Comment: Mike, to answer your question when dealing with UUIDs as the primary key there is a lot of the array dynamic property setting and find myself repeating the 2 lines of code to set and reset, etc. 2 lines of code in a large application results in overhead.  P.S. the above mentioned was a tag for duplication which has since been removed. The duplication tag was for multi approaches to clearing arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use computed properties to do this in one line:

```
$scope.view.state = {[id]: true};
```

However, this will only work on the latest browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari 7.1+, and Edge) and if you have any build steps that need to parse your code they will also need to be upgraded to understand the syntax as well.

If you need older browser support (or if your build tools cannot be upgraded) then you'll need to do it in two steps.  However, you can hide those steps in a function:

```
function initialState(key, value) {
  var result = {};
  result[key] = value;
  return result;
}
```

then you can simply do:

```
$scope.view.state = initialState(id, true);
```

Comment: Sean, thanks a million. Based on your answer I will stick with 2 lines as some of my users will have older browsers. I'm suspect the reason for browser dependency is version of angular/ js? I'll go do some research as I'm intrigued