# empty array inside an ko.observable

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have an `ko.observable` with an object that contains 3 arrays like this:

```
self.filter({ file: [], site: [], statut: [] })`
```

When I try to empty them it doesn't work. I tried

```
array = []
```

to empty them. Is it a problem with the observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all of your observable object's arrays to be observable to be able to update the UI, although I'd certainly (like the other answerer) advice you to do so.

I would like to explain however *why* it doesn't work.

Say you have the following code:

```
var originalObject = {
  myArray: [1, 2, 3]
};

var myObservable = ko.observable(originalObject);

// Resetting the array behind knockout's back:
originalObject.myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

The last line changes a property of the object that was used to *set* the observable. There's no way for knockout to know you've updated your object. If you want knockout to reconsider the observable's vale, you have to tell it something's changed:

```
myObservable.valueHasMutated();
```

Now, normally, you update an observable by passing a new or updated variable to it like so:

```
myObservable(newValue);
```

Strangely, setting the observable with the same object again also works:

```
myObservable(originalObject);
```

This is why:

Internally, knockout compares the `newValue` to the value it currently holds. If the values are the same, it doesn't do anything. If they're different, it sets the new value and performs the necessary UI updates.

Now, if you're working with just a `boolean` or `number`, you'll notice knockout has no problems figuring out if the new value is actually different:

```js
var simpleObservable = ko.observable(true);

simpleObservable.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  console.log("Observable changed to: " + newValue);
});

simpleObservable(true);   // Doesn't log
simpleObservable(false);  // Does log
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

For objects however, it behaves differently:

```js
var myObject = { a: 1 };
var simpleObservable = ko.observable(myObject);

simpleObservable.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  console.log("Observable changed to: " + JSON.stringify(newValue, null, 2));
});

simpleObservable(myObject);   // Does log, although nothing changed
simpleObservable({b: 2 });     // Does log
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

The subscription is triggered, even though we've used the exact same object to reset our observable! If you dig through knockout's source code, you'll see why. It uses this method to check if the new value is different:

```
var primitiveTypes = { 'undefined':1, 'boolean':1, 'number':1, 'string':1 };
function valuesArePrimitiveAndEqual(a, b) {
  var oldValueIsPrimitive = (a === null) || (typeof(a) in primitiveTypes);
  return oldValueIsPrimitive ? (a === b) : false;
}
```

Simply put: if the old value isn't a primitive value, it will just assume things have changed. This means we can update our `originalObject`, as long as we reset the observable.

```
originalObject.myArray.length = 0;
myObservable(originalObject);
```

Or, just as easy:

```
myObservable(Object.assign(originalObject, { myArray: [] });
```

A bit of a long answer, but I believe it's nice to know *why* stuff doesn't work, instead of only circumventing it. Even if simply using `observableArray`s and letting knockout optimize its work is the better solution!

Answer (score 1):

You mention "*emptying*" an array. Note that that's different from "*assigning a new, empty array to a variable*". At any rate, if you want to "empty" an array:

1. For `observableArray` check [the relevant docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), because they have a `removeAll()` utility method.
2. For emptying a plain javascript array, check [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1232040/419956) that has various solutions, one of which is simply `array.length = 0`.

As a final note, if you're inside the view model, you might need to do `self.filter()` first to get the object inside the observable. So, for example:

```
self.filter().file.length = 0; // plain array method
```

However, since `file`, `site`, and `statut` are plain arrays (and not `observableArray`s) there will be no automatic updates in your UI. If they *were* observable arrays, you'd do:

```
self.filter().file.removeAll(); // assuming `file` has been made observable
```