# How to delete array value by splice?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Stuck in delete array value by `splice` .Tried with delete and splice doesn't work..

```
var arr = [];
 arr[2] = 22;
 arr[5] = 3;
 arr[99] = 3343;
 for(var i in arr){
    if(i != 2){
    arr.splice(i,1);
    }
   //delete arr[i];
 }
 console.log(arr);// [2: 22, 98: 3343]
 //wanted [2:22]
```

I want to delete all except index `2` ,It is only delete one.

Comment: What do you mean remove array value? remove as in remove the item in the array? If you just want to empty an array you could use different ways. [See this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/1504480)

Comment: `for (var i=0;i<arr.length;) {
  arr.splice(i, 1);
}`

Comment: `while (arr.length!=0) { arr.splice(0, 1); }`

Comment: `arr.length=0` ... done. First approach above `arr=[]` will break reference to original array. And don't use `for in` on an array

Answer (score 1):

No need of a for loop in the splice, you may use: `arr.splice(0,arr.length)`

But if you want to just delete all elements just do `arr=[]`.

Alternative method would be to loop & `pop`:

```
while(arr.length > 0) {
    arr.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you might need to get a sequential item by item deletion starting from the the middle of an array you should iterate in reverse in order not to get the shifting indexes get in front of you.

```js
var arr = new Array(10).fill("").map((e,i) => e = "item:" +i),
      i = 7;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
while (i>2) console.log(JSON.stringify(arr.splice(i--,1))); // splice item at index i and decrease i by one
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```