# Angular 2 Child Component removing Item from Parent Component Array

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently having issue with Child component trying to remove Parent component's Array.

Parent Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/parent.html'
})

export class ParentComponent {

    public items = [];
}
```

Parent HTML

```
  <child [items]="items"></child>
  <product *ngFor="let item of items><product>
```

Child component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/child.html'
})

export class ChildComponent{
    @Input() items;

    emptyItems() {
        this.items = [];
    }
    addItem() {
        this.items.push({'title': 'foo'});
    }
}
```

However when I call emptyItems/addItem function, the items array in the child view will reflect on changes, however on the parent component it doesnt change.

Do I need to use Output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to use `Output` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#

However we can use two-ways binding on your `items`, this will reflect changes on both sides:

```
<child [(items)]="items"></child>
```

See more details https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

**Update**:
Try to empty you array differently [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

`Output` should work https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Output-var.html
The idea is that you have to pass updated things from *child* to *parent* and manually update member `items` of the *parent*

Comment: that didnt work for me, I called emptyItems function and was hoping it wont display any item however it didnt do anything to the parent object