# How to remove all the elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have an array eg: `a[3,4,5,6,7,8]`. I want to remove all the element in one time and make array as an empty array. How to remove all the element of an array.

My code

```
var a = [2,3,4,5,6];
for(var i=0; I<a.length; i++){
a.remove();
}
```

Comment: `a.length = 0` asked many times

Comment: Learn : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.length = 0;
```

This is all what you need

```js
var a = [2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(a);
a.length = 0;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: inside `for` loop ?

Comment: no, you don't need loops.

Comment: Thank, clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do `a.length = 0;` if you don't want to lose references. Do `a = [];` if you want to lose references.