# Angular JS Blank option in Select when trying to remove all ng options values

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS.

I am trying to clear all the option values from the dropdown except the default "---select---" option.

But then an extra blank option is being created in the dropdown. I am unable to remove this blank option

Probably because $scope.screenResponse is empty.
How can I make the dropdown with just the "---Select---" option?

JS Controller code:

```
delete $scope.screenResponse;
```

HTML code:

```
<select ng-model="messageSource" name="messageSource" ng-options="object.id as object.value for object in screenResponse ">
        <option value="" >--Select--</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$scope.screenResponse = "";
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/81t6cbjw/344/)

Comment: This would still create the Blank option

Answer (score 0):

Do this inside your controller code where you performed `delete`

```
$scope.screenResponse.length = 0;
```

Setting the length property of an array to zero will make it empty.

Reference: [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1232040/17447)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/amw94yn4/

Comment: Like this? ng-options="object.id as object.value for object in screenResponse.length>0 "

Comment: No. Inside the controller