# Creating div and adding a background image to it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I've managed to make a div in the place where I wanted it to be, but when it comes to adding a background image, I just can't do it.

I'm creating divs with the loop and then I'm trying to add a background image to it in the **same** loop. I don't know if that's the problem or something else, if that's the case, please help me make another.

I tried doing something like `itemContainer[i]` but I can't get that to work either.

Update: the reason is that my array is empty, don't really know what I'm doing wrong though.

```
var cicon = [];

$.ajax({
    url: '/json/test.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.test).each(function(index, value) {
            cicon.push(value.Icon);
            /*console.log(value.Icon) works here, 
            so there's something wrong when I'm adding it to the array.*/
        });
    }
});

for (var i = 0, n = 10; i < n; i++) {
    var itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
    itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
    itemContainer.innerHTML = "item" + i;

    itemContainer.style.width = "86px";
    itemContainer.style.height = "86px";
    itemContainer.style.margin = "5px";
    itemContainer.style.border = "2px solid black";
    itemContainer.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    itemContainer.style.float = "left";

    var iconstring = 'url(\'' + cicon[i] + '\')';
    itemContainer.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
    itemContainer.style.backgroundImage = iconstring;


    document.getElementById('page').appendChild(itemContainer);
}
```

If anyone is wondering, the array contains urls that look like this: https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/440/icons/earbuds.f6dc85683202f2530ae8728880f4a47d4b013ea8.png

Comment: @Jecoms that slash is escaping the ' . I would use `"url('"+ cicon[i] + "')"` myself, but this is valid

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yes, of course. Mind compiler was in interpolation mode and also trimmed the outer string single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you re-declare:

```
var cicon = [];
```

you are simply emptying the array variable. [(how do i empty an array in javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Example:

```js
var cicon = [];

function doWork() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cicon.length; i++) {
    var itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
    itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
    itemContainer.innerHTML = "item" + i;

    itemContainer.style.width = "86px";
    itemContainer.style.height = "86px";
    itemContainer.style.margin = "5px";
    itemContainer.style.border = "2px solid black";
    itemContainer.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    itemContainer.style.float = "left";

    var iconstring = 'url(\'' + cicon[i] + '\')';
    itemContainer.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
    itemContainer.style.backgroundImage = iconstring;


    document.getElementById('page').appendChild(itemContainer);
  }
}
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/json/BotCopper.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      $(data.BotCopper).each(function (index, value) {
        cicon.push(value.Icon);
        doWork();
      });
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // this is only for test
      cicon = ['https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/1.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/2.jpg',
               'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/3.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/4.jpg',
               'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/5.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/6.jpg',
               'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/7.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/8.jpg',
               'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/9.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/10.jpg'];
      doWork();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="page"></div>
```

Instead, removing the line:

```
var cicon = [];
```

the result is:

```js
window.onload = function() {
            var cicon = ['https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/1.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/2.jpg',
                'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/3.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/4.jpg',
                'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/5.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/6.jpg',
                'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/7.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/8.jpg',
                'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/9.jpg', 'https://rawgit.com/Pixabay/jQuery-flexImages/master/images/10.jpg'];


            for (var i = 0, n = 10; i < n; i++) {
                var itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
                itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
                itemContainer.innerHTML = "item" + i;

                itemContainer.style.width = "86px";
                itemContainer.style.height = "86px";
                itemContainer.style.margin = "5px";
                itemContainer.style.border = "2px solid black";
                itemContainer.style.borderRadius = "10px";
                itemContainer.style.float = "left";

                var iconstring = 'url(\'' + cicon[i] + '\')';
                itemContainer.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
                itemContainer.style.backgroundImage = iconstring;


                document.getElementById('page').appendChild(itemContainer);
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: I placed that in the wrong place. I'm declaring that before I'm adding stuff to it and not using it in my function. Sorry for that. I'm actually parsing a json file and adding values from there to my array. I'll try this again tomorrow, don't know what i did wrong.

Comment: Well, ehm. That's probably it. But I'll try it out tomorrow and accept your answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: It worked, kinda. It's repeating a couple of images over and over. It seems like if I have (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) it repeats 20 images (cicon 0-19) 429 times. I did change it by removing the test array. Nvm, it makes sense actually. I think if I do i < 429 I get the right thing.

Comment: I tried it but it can't handle all 429, so it crashes. Idk really, I'll try to figure something out. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @EagL Your browser is limited like any one! There is no solution for this: too many images.... So, finally, now you could accept and upvote?

Comment: Yeah I understand, I was going to cut down the number of images anyways. I've already accepted and upvoted :)

Comment: @EagL Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your script but you need elements in `cicon`. e.g

`var cicon = ["url1","url2",...];`

Check here for a working example: [Div Background image](https://jsfiddle.net/hcjc0sL0/)

Comment: Yeah, I'm adding them in another function, so it's not empty.