# How to iterate over array in reverse order with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I want to iterate over an array in reverse order using Lodash. Is that possible?

My code looks like below.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
_.each(array, function(i) {
   _.remove(array, i);
});
```

When I do `_.pullAt(array, 0)` new array is `[2, 3, 4, 5]`. All array elements shifted to left by 1 position, and current index is pointing to element 3. After next iteration, 3 will get deleted and then 5. After 3rd iteration array contains `[2, 4]` which I couldn't delete.

If I iterate over the array in reverse order, then this problem won't arise. In Lodash, can I iterate over an array in reverse order?

Comment: You want to empty the array then?

Comment: Also, both `_.remove` and `_.pullAt` aren't in underscore. Are you using lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript) if you only want that and *choose your weapon*.

Otherwise, strictly answering the question, to iterate the indices from the length of the array to zero, you could use the ["down-to" `-->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator-in-c)<sup>1</sup>. But that's not really necessary, even underscore isn't necessary in this case as the [`.pop` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) is enough.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    index = arr.length;

while (index --> 0) {
    console.log(index);
    arr.pop();
}
console.log(arr);
```

If you're using Lodash like the functions referenced in the question seem to indicate, you could use [`_.eachRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#forEachRight).

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

_.eachRight(arr, function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  arr.pop();
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

<sup>*<sup>1</sup> The down-to operator doesn't exist and is only a `--` decrement followed by a `>` comparison.*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can use `_.reverse` available in version 4:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array = _.reverse(array)
console.log(array)
//5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```