# Node array scope issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, scope

I feel like this is a pretty stupid question, but I'm having trouble understanding why I'm seeing strange behavior in a callback function. 
I defined an array called clientList which I export and use in other files. This code here is run when a client connects to my server.

When I say clientList.splice or clientList.push, everything works as expected, and the clinetList array reflects my change in other files which require() it in. However, if I say assign ClientList directly (e.g. clientList = []) then that change is not reflected in other files. If I print the contents of ClientList inside the callback, the change is reflected either way.

```
var clientList = [];

module.exports.socketHandler = (socket) => {
var client = new Client(socket);
clientList.push(client);

socket.on('end',function(){
    clientList = [] //This does not change the exported array
    clientList.splice(0,1); //This does change the exported array
    console.log("Client connection ended: "+clientList.length); //This always changes
});

}

module.exports.clientList = clientList;


//IN A DIFFERENT FILE
//This code is run every few seconds on a loop
var example = require('./sockets.js');
console.log("Array Size: "+example.clientList.length);
```

My question is why there is a difference here. I have a good understanding of javascript scope and asynchronous operations, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what's causing this behavior. Is this related to how the node module loader works? Or am I just missing something obvious? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: That's interesting. I know that javascript passes values in this way, but since I didn't explicitly pass any arguments it didn't occur to me. So even if you just reference a variable in the parent scope, the same rules apply?

Comment: When you have got refrences to an array you should'nt empty it like that. use other methods like `clientList.lenght=0`. See: [how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/5048383)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly in this line:

```
clientList = [] //This does not change the exported array
```

Doing this you are not emptying the array, but assigning a new one in that variable. But you already exported the old one, so that's because it's not being reflected in the other files.

Someone already put in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258288/node-array-scope-issue#comment69717562_41258288) how to empty an array, in your case I would use method 2 or 3 (2 is the most common one I'd say).