# How do you see if an element has content (or is empty) in Angular 2 template?

Tags: jquery, angular, angularjs-directive

When I click on a button on my page, an event fires, and dynamically updates the DOM if there is relative content.

But I want to be able to clear the DOM when the button is clicked again, and then provide the results.  Clicking again currently just adds more and more content, which is no good.

I've been trying to do this in Angular, and have been having trouble.

#### my template

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="articles-container" #element>
    <div class="article" *ngFor="let article of allMatches">


      <div class="article-image"> <img src="{{article.image}}" alt=""> </div>

<div class="title-wrapper">
  <div class="article-info">
    <a href="{{article.url}}"> <h3> {{ article.title }} </h3> </a>
    <div class="article-description">  {{ article.description }} </div>
  </div>

  <div class="source-wrapper">
    <div class="article-thumb"> <img src="{{article.thumbnail}}" alt=""> </div>
    <div class="article-source"> {{ article.source }} </div>
  </div>
</div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've been trying to grab the #element tag, and using jQuery to see if it is empty or not.  But it just breaks the app.

i.e.

```
 // if ($("#element").is(':empty)') ) {
    //  
    //     console.log("empty");
    //   }
```

I'm trying to do this at the very top of my function (the one fired when the button is clicked), so it checks if the div has content or not, and if it does, empty it, then provide the new content.

I've read using jQuery is discouraged in Angular2.  What is the better way?

Comment: where is the `button` in your code?

Comment: Please post your controller as well.

Comment: The button uses an Event Emitter, which then calls a function in a separate component.  It's in that function that I am trying to empty the div.

Comment: We might be able to help more if you post your function (and component that it's in) that's supposed to clear the `allMatches` array.

Answer (score 0):

You are not thinking in angular way. You should leave the template alone and handle this in the contoller.

It means you should empty `allMatches` array in the controller:

```
allMatches.length = 0;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work to empty the current div of matches.  This approach has me curious though.

Comment: I am pretty sure if you can provide a plunkr, we can solve your issue quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure you can directly set the length of an array like that. `allMatches = [];` may work better.

Comment: @FedericoP I am sure that you can directly set the length of array to 0 to empty the array. While `arr = []` creates a new array, the former empties the array.

Comment: @s.alem Yep you're right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should modify the `allMatches` array since you know that the content of the array is all that's populating the `articles-container` div. If you change the array, you change the DOM.

```
let newMatches = [{title: 'This is a match'}]; // example data

allMatches = []; // clears the data

setTimeout(() => {
  allMatches = newMatches;
}, 1500); // loads data in 1.5 seconds
```

If some boilerplate HTML shows up when the array is empty, you can all add an `*ngIf` to the `articles-container` div so that it only is added to the DOM when the array is populated.

```
<div class="articles-container" *ngIf="allMatches.length > 0">
    <!-- content (*ngFor articles) -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!  The timeout works to clear the div when the search is initiated.  For some reason the array is still holding the previous matches and reprinting them after the search.

Comment: Right now, I'm keeping the matches arrays as global so I can access them from the DOM, as setting them locally in the event with let or var doesn't allow access from the template.

Comment: To access the variable from the template you could declare it with `public varName;` in the component class and then modify it later in your function by accessing it with `this.varName`.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah I tried doing that, but no dice.  It's like once the array is populated, it can't be cleared from within the event function.  Strange