# How to reset array to empty in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

In project I define an empty array `var reply= [];` and in a portion of code and conditions I had o reset it to its origin as an empty array. any one can help how to do this instead of using pop method.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: `reply = []`? or what are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks. reply = [] was great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

some times tiny questions are looking so big.
try:

```
reply = [];
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to set length of an array to zero or use splice.

```
reply.length = 0
// or 
reply.splice(0, reply.length)
```

setting it to [] will create a new array.