# How to push an array to a file without keeping old data when looping in setInterval?

Tags: arrays, node.js

sorry for the title, I was trying to be specific but it's a bit confusing. Actually the piece of code should be the better way to show you what my problem is:

```
var i = 0
var jsonArray = []
var startTime = new Date().getTime()

var writeFile = setInterval(function () {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime()
    var stopTime = 31 * 1000
    var executeScript = setInterval(function () {
        // the script will stop after some time
        if (currentTime - startTime > stopTime) { // time in ms: 60 * 60 * 1000 = 1 hour
            process.exit()
        }
        // making request and fetching data
        http.get(request, function (response) {
            response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
                if (err) return console.error(err)
                response.setEncoding('utf8')
                parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                    result = result.SoccerFeed.SoccerDocument[0].MatchData[0].TeamData
                    // creating object and filling it with received data
                    result = createJsObject(result)
                    // converting object in json format
                    var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)
                    jsonArray.push(jsonObject)
                    // copying json into a new file without overwriting previous written data
                })
            }))
        }).on('error', console.error)
    }, 1 * 1000) // interval in ms: 90 * 1000 = 90 seconds / 1 min 30
    fs.writeFile('API - Opta - ' + moment().format('YYYY - DD.MM (HH:mm:ss)') + '.txt', jsonArray, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err
    })
    jsonArray = []
    i++
}, 10 * 1000)
```

The problem is that the array I'm pushing in the file is keeping data from the old one, even when I clean it with jsonArray = []. I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I just want to create a new file every x minutes with an array that doesn't contain the data from the previous saved file. With this code, the file saves the array every x minutes but every next file will keep the data of the old arrays/objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at first I thought it was an asynchronous problem with fs.writeFile getting a blank copy of jsonArray.  This is not the case due to the way that javascript handles jsonArray = [].  When you make the call to fs.writeFile, you pass it jsonArray which is passed by "reference."  When you set it to jsonArray = [] you actually create an entire new object.  The object that was passed to fs.writeFile is no longer referenced by jsonArray and it's only scope is in the call to fs.writeFile thus it maintains the state that you passed in.  If you had instead called jsonArray.length = 0 it would have always output an empty array to the file because that would have overwritten the actual array fs.writeFile.  Check out this post to see that:  [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

In short, that's not the problem.

But the actual problem is that http.get is receiving data many times after the file was written.  Those things won't get written until your next loop.  Your described sequence that things are always one behind makes perfect sense.

Your sequence is this inside your interval executeScript:

1. Check to make sure it's not quitting time
2. Start http.get

   - sometime in the future the response is received and added to jsonArray
3. Start fs.writeFile, contents of jsonArray locked in at this point in time as to what is going to be written to the file

   - sometime in future the file is written
4. Set jsonArray = []

I would propose you have two separate intervals that aren't nested like so:

```
var i = 0
var jsonArray = []
var startTime = new Date().getTime()

var writeFile = setInterval(function () {
    fs.writeFile('API - Opta - ' + moment().format('YYYY - DD.MM (HH:mm:ss)') + '.txt', jsonArray, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err
    })
    jsonArray = []
    i++
}, 10 * 1000)

var executeScript = setInterval(function () {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime()
    var stopTime = 31 * 1000

    // the script will stop after some time
    if (currentTime - startTime > stopTime) { // time in ms: 60 * 60 * 1000 = 1 hour
        process.exit()
    }
    // making request and fetching data
    http.get(request, function (response) {
        response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
            if (err) return console.error(err)
            response.setEncoding('utf8')
            parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                result = result.SoccerFeed.SoccerDocument[0].MatchData[0].TeamData
                // creating object and filling it with received data
                result = createJsObject(result)
                // converting object in json format
                var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)
                jsonArray.push(jsonObject)
                // copying json into a new file without overwriting previous written data
            })
        }))
    }).on('error', console.error)
}, 1 * 1000) // interval in ms: 90 * 1000 = 90 seconds / 1 min 30
```

Now you have two intervals going at the same time.  The 1 second loop on executing the script now has lots of data queued up for when the 10 second loop on writing the file kicks off.  It writes the file and then immediately clears jsonArray for it to keep adding in subsequent 1 second loops of the executeScript interval.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your quick answer. I only tried #3 at the moment, but it didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong, I only replaced jsonArray by JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonArray)) but I kept all the code I wrote. Did I make any mistake? Edit: Even fs.writeFileSync doesn't work... :(

Comment: Ok, I got it.  I missed something in what you are doing.  I'll update my answer.  We'll get this working for you.  It's an asynchronous thing and a variable scope thing.

Comment: Wow I'm impressed, works like a charm. Thanks a lot for the clear explanation and the time you took to help me!

Comment: The best thanks you can give on stack overflow is to vote up my question and mark it as the answer! :)

Comment: I tried but: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". By the way, I don't understand why but yesterday it seemed to work but only displayed part of the requested data (only 'away' team, not 'home' team, it worked before the change). And now it only saves one file and doesn't seems to repeat the action... I'll try to find a solution by myself because I need to make this script work for tonight but if you have any idea, your help is more than welcome! I will copy/paste the actual code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but place this line

```
var jsonArray = []
```

after this

```
var writeFile = setInterval(function () {
```

and you won't need to clear jsonArray.

so it will be

```
var writeFile = setInterval(function () {
  var jsonArray = []
  // ...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've already tried it but it didn't work, all the arrays are empty now. There is another problem in my code by the way, first copy in the file is always empty, i understand why but i don't know how to prevent it.

Comment: It's just an assumption because it's difficult to help you without debugging, but  your http request probably returns the same data for each request and that's the reason why each new file has the same data..