# Splice is not working perfectly to remove all the array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, array-splice

I have User angular.forEach to push all the data and I have to remove all the data which I was pushed, So I used splice but it's not working. What I have to do instead of splice or is any method to remove all array.

Following is my code:

```
angular.forEach($scope.resourcedetails, function(resdata) {

          console.log(resdata);
          var removelength =   $scope.resourcedetails.length;
          $scope.adduser.push(resdata);
          console.log($scope.adduser.length);
          if (removelength >=0) {
          $scope.resourcedetails.splice(0, removelength)
          }


         });
```

Comment: `$scope.resourcedetails` is an array or object?.. You can apply `.length` to an array

Comment: Its an array. I fixed my issue. Thank You For your Reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just assign an empty array to do this..

```
$scope.resourcedetails = [];
```

Take a look at this [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)