# Delete all objects in Object/Array

Tags: javascript

could you help me with code which delete all objects in array?

in my example i have array which contains Objects.

Every object contains keys and i want to look at every key and check if it is Object.

If it is Object i want to delete that key( In my example i just rewrite its value to empty string)

```
   if(typeof result2.length == 'number'){
    for(var u in result2){
    Object.keys(result2[u])
.filter(k => typeof result2[u][k] === 'object')
.map(k => delete result2[u][k])
}
}else{
    Object.keys(result2)
.filter(k => typeof result2[k] === 'object')
.map(k => delete result2[k])
}
```

My code which works if result2 containts more Objects.

If it contain only 1 object it does not work.

If input contain only 1 object its change from array to object.

Comment: please add the *object* and the wanted result as well. btw, an empty string does not delete a property.

Comment: Try this `result2.forEach(o => {
      Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
        if(typeof o[k] === 'object')
          delete o[k];
      });
    });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Realy? there is no one see that i need to work with objects

Answer (score 0):

Replace `result2[u][p] = "";` on `delete result2[u][p]`

You can alse make it:

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: {s: "dsdfsdf"}
};

Object.keys(object1)
.filter(k => typeof object1[k] === 'object')
.every(k => delete object1[k])

console.log(object1);
```

Comment: if i i edit your example it works, until my array contain only 1 object. if my array contains only 1 object it crash as my code.  for(var u in result2){


Object.keys(result2[u])
.filter(k => typeof result2[u][k] === 'object')
.map(k => delete result2[u][k])
console.log(result2);
}

Comment: Could you paste example of your object result2, that should not working for you?

Comment: It is on 2.input (bad scenario) Array contain only 1 Object(no Index). There is maybe problem that if array contains only 1 object its automatically change to Object

Comment: It sounds like "above" logic generate incorrect data.