# How to clear a typed array in typescript and preserving its type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Now in a class, I declared an array with type: CustomType, like below

```
class Example {
  public exampleArray: CustomType[];
  public clearArray() {
    this.exampleArray = [];
  }
}
```

As you can see the clearArray assign an UNDEFINED type of an empty array, which seems lost the type information.

How I can clear the array but preserving its declared type?

Comment: Would `exampleArray.length = 0` do? It works in JS, not sure if TS accepts it.

Comment: The type information isn't lost here in the first place. What's your actual problem? This sounds like an XY question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @LW001 not really a duplicate of that .. the OP is worried that type safety is lost when you assign an untyped empty array to the field (which is not and is type safe)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Sorry just a wrong click

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The type information is determined by the type annotation on the field (`exampleArray: CustomType[]`). At runtime Javascript arrays are untyped anyway. The compiler will allow an empty array (`[]`) to be assigned to anything as this is considered safe, since there are no objects inside, it can be an array of `CustomType`. The field type will then prevent you form pushing to the array objects of any other type:

```
class CustomType { x: number}
class Example {
    public exampleArray: CustomType[];
    public clearArray() {
        this.exampleArray = [];
        this.exampleArray.push(new CustomType())
        this.exampleArray.push({}) // error not a `CustomType`
    }
}
```

**Note**

If this had been a variable with no type annotation, the variable would have been inferred to `any[]`, which can lead to problems (types are not checked on either when assigning an array literal or when you would push to the array):

```
let noAnnotationArray = [] //  any[]
```

In this case, adding a type annotation is still the best way to go. Type assertions (as suggested in other answers) can lead to uncaught errors if later someone adds an item to the array:

```
let withAnnotation:CustomType[] = [{}] //  error
let withAssertion = <CustomType[]>[{}] // no error even though we assign {}
```

Answer (score 8):

This post seems to be out of date. There is a new way to do this.

```
this.array = [] as CustomType[];
```

Comment: Why use a type assertion ? the type of the array is already determined by the annotation on `array`. The `as` is equivalent to the `let withAssertion = <CustomType[]>[{}]` which I explain why is a bad idea

Comment: Thanks @Luke Becker. What the comment above says is wrong, because the as <type> is for the [] instance you pass as new array, so thanks!.

Answer (score 4):

There can be 3 ways of emptying an array

1. setting its length = 0

   `myArr.length = 0;`
2. using *splice* method Array

   `myArr.splice(0,myArr.length);`
3. Pop() each element of array

   ```
   while(myArr.length){
     myArr.pop();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

> You can always clear the list items by changing the length
>   property to 0

eg: `this.exampleArray.length = 0`

Setting length to 0 clears all the elements in the array without altering the reference of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Clean the array even if is passed as paramener through a method::

```
myArray.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with

```
this.exampleArray = <CustomType[]>[];
```

Comment: It would be <CustomType[]>[] but what do you gain ? Nothing .