# Delete all elements in an array - Function appends 'undefined' at the array end

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

Here is my code

```
var x = [];

function random(min,max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (min-max))+min;
}
function random2(a, b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    x.push(random(0,b));
  }
}
random2(5, 100);
console.log(x); // [ -43, -27, -38, -21, -79 ]

x.splice(0, x.length);
x.push(random2(5,100));
console.log(x); // [ -24, -97, -99, -43, -66, undefined ]
```

I simply wanna remove all the elements in the array then add new elements in it.
But when I try to do it with the code above, `undefined` is also adding to the array. 
 How can I prevent it?

Comment: why not just reset it with `x = []`?

Comment: so, what about `x = [];` instead of splicing and whatever?

Comment: or `x.length = 0;`

Comment: Why don't you just assign empty array to it? 'x=[]'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: You're asking a wrong question. You should ask "why `undefined` is appearing to the array" instead of what you assume causing your real problem.

Comment: it should be `max-min`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to puish the function call, which returns `undefined`, but just call the function `random2`, because the function itselft add the elements to the array.

```js
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (min - max)) + min;
}

function random2(a, b) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        x.push(random(0, b));
    }
}

var x = [];

random2(5, 100);
console.log(x);

x.length = 0;          // better performance than x.splice(0, x.length)
random2(5,100);        // call without using push
console.log(x);        // no undefined anymore
```

A better approach is to return an array in `random2`, because this function does not access an outer defined array. To push the values, you could take the spread syntax.

```js
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (min - max)) + min;
}

function random2(a, b) {
    return Array.from({ length: a }, _ => random(0, b));
}

var x = random2(5, 100);
console.log(x);

x.length = 0;          
x.push(...random2(5, 100));
console.log(x);
```

Comment: @nina, Out of the context, isn't it should be `random(a,b)` inside `random2` method, assuming the OP need to create `min` number of random numbers between `min` and `max` values ? Even the OP is wrong in his implementation.

Comment: @VigneshRaja, please ask op.

Answer (score 1):

To empty an array, there are multiple ways as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript) with some benchmark results and explanation regarding their performance.

As an aggregation, asssume `var a = [1,2,3,4,5]`

1. `a = []`
2. `a.length = 0`
3. `a.splice(0, a.length)`
4. `a = new Array()`
5. `while(a.pop()){}`
6. `while(a.shift()){}`

You have called the function `random2` inside the push method. So `random2` method first inserts the values in the array `x` and returns the default value `undefined` ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Description)), which in turn gets pushed into the array. Hence the value.

Comment: Thank you. That's correct, couldn't realise that first but thank to Nina, helped me realise that.

Comment: Glad you got it. :)

Comment: @uhbc Out of the context, isn't it should be `random(a,b)` inside `random2` method, assuming you need to create `min` number of random numbers between `min` and `max` values ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the length to zero

```
x.length = 0;
```