# How to reset an array that is outside function scope

Tags: javascript

I don't know exactly how to title this but here is an exemple

I pass an array to a function, and I want that all the changed inside the function are applied to the array that was passed by ref (event the []) =>

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
function resetter(arr){
   arr = []
}
resetter(myArray); // still  [1,2,3,4] because I assign a new object
```

but I want that changed to be applied to my array I passed as a reference

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
function resetter(arr){
   arr.length = 0;
}
resetter(myArray); // [] but is this clean ?
```

are there any other way ?

Comment: Setting the length is a good way to truncate items and this method is supported by the spec.

Comment: oki thank :) a long as it is not considered an hack I am good to go

Comment: You can give a read to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

If two variables have same reference it means that modifying(changing property) one of them will change another. It doesn't mean that assigning one with new value will change another value.

You can use `splice()`

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
function resetter(arr){
   arr.splice(0,arr.length)
}
resetter(myArray);

console.log(myArray)
```

Consider if you want to change the array to whole new array not just `[]`. You can pass another array using spread operator to `splice()`

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
function resetter(arr, newArray){
   arr.splice(0,arr.length,...newArray)
}
resetter(myArray, ['str1','str2']);

console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Isn't that what they are doing in the OP?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Updated the answer.