# How do you empty an array in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

As the question above says, how can I empty an array? I tried using `useState` setting the array like this `setArray([])` but this actually doesn't not work properly because some times the array doesn't reset completly, is there another way to empty it?

Code:

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
const functionName = (value) => {
        //reset the array first
        setArray([]);
        setArray([value]);
    }
```

Comment: check this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: `setArray([])` will definitely set the array to an empty array. Why are you then calling `setArray([value])` right after it?

Comment: because I want to insert new values inside the array each time the user selects an option, so the array would have new values after being reseted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to call `setArray([]);` when your ultimate goal is to change the value of the array to the `value` that is passed down from your function.

The reason why it probably doesn't update from time to time is because the Virtual DOM hasn't seen any changes at all or you're not iterating over them correctly.

If you're changing the values of an array using `useState` and looping over them and returning components, make sure to always set the `key` property of your elements, which should be set to a unique identifier, so the Virtual DOM can function properly. For more information, please read the React documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

To answer your question in regards to clearing arrays: you can clear arrays by setting the variable to `null`.

```
let exampleArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(exampleArray);
exampleArray = null;
console.log(exampleArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mgfq75e2/

Do note that if you're using the `useState` hook, it might take a couple of cycles before the changes are visible in your rendered output since it is executed asynchronously.

If you want to know when the state is actually updated, you could use the `useEffect` hook and pass your (array) variable so it fires when the state is updated:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Example = () => {
    const [exampleArray, setExampleArray] = useState(['a', 'b', 'c']);

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setExampleArray(null);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(exampleArray);
    }, [exampleArray]);

    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Test</button>
    );

};

export default Example;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-faraday-n429p?file=/src/App.js

For more information, please take a look at the React docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 1):

with spread operator you can do it without resetting.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
const functionName = (value) => {
    setArray([...value]);
}
```