# Removing every other word from an array (passage of text)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been very stuck on a bonus task from a tutorial, which is to remove every other word (contained in the array `overusedWords`) from the main passage `betterWords` (a long array of words making up a story).

For reference:

```
let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
```

Focusing just on the word `'really'`, here is what I have come up with, with no success so far.

```
for (let word of betterWords) {  
     if (word === 'really' && word % 2 !== 0) { 
        betterWords.splice(word, 1) 
     } 
}
```

Any advice welcome, thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you explain better your question? What are you trying to achieve? Which words do you need to remove from `overusedWords` array?

Comment: Hi Riccardo, all of them, but here I was just focusing on 'really'.

Comment: So you need to clear `overusedWords` array, whatever values it contains. You should check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/9864539. This answer explains all the possible ways in Javascript to clear an array.

Comment: Thanks, I will review that now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

1. Put `overusedWords` items in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/set)
2. Define a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store word-count pairs
3. Iterate over `betterWords` using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), in each iteration:

   - If the word is included in `overusedWords` `set`:

     - Get `count` of the current `word` in the passage until now
     - if it's `even`, add it to the resulting array
     - increment the `count` of this `word` by 1
   - Else, always add it to the resulting array

In the end, you will have the `betterWords` array with the words of `overusedWords` removed every other time they appeared:

```js
const overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
const betterWords = ['hello','basically', 'really', 'very', 'really', 'very', 'basically', 'very', 'really', 'basically', 'really', 'very', 'basically', 'really','bye'];
const map = new Map();
const set = new Set(overusedWords);

const res = betterWords.reduce((acc,word) => {
  if (set.has(word)) {
    const wordCount = map.get(word) || 0;
    if (wordCount%2 === 0) {
      console.log(word, wordCount);
      acc.push(word);
    }
    map.set(word, wordCount+1);
  } else {
    acc.push(word);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. A little advanced for me at the moment but I will store for future reference and try to break it down.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let betterWord of betterWords) {  
         if (overusedWords.includes(betterWord)) { 
           let removedIndex = betterWords.indexOf(value);
            if (removedIndex > -1) {
              betterWords.splice(removedIndex, 1);
            }
         } 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant and gives me so much clarity on moving forward. This code removed EVERY word from the passage, rather than every other word :).

I have modified the code as such but still with no luck (sorry that the code is hard to read):

`for (let word of betterWords) {  
    if (overusedWords.includes(word)) { 
      let removedIndex = betterWords.indexOf(word);
       if (removedIndex > -1 && removedIndex % 2 === 0) {
         betterWords.splice(removedIndex, 1);
       }
    } 
}`