# if I alter javascript array length to a smaller value would this cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-leaks

If I have an array of 1000 elements and I set the array length to 10, where the other element will go? Will that cause a memory leak?

Comment: You cannot update an array length after its created. You can remove items from it which will update its length.

Comment: @SteveTomlin Sure you can set the length

Comment: @SteveTomlin [uhhh, what?](https://jsbin.com/liqawuzecu/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where the other element will go?

The properties `10` to `999` will get deleted when you assign `.length = 10`.

Setting `.length = 0` is a well-known solution for [emptying an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/1048572).

> Will that cause a memory leak?

No, they will get garbage-collected normally.

Answer (score 2):

The [ECMAScript specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length) are saying that the elements are `deleted`:

> Reducing the value of the "length" property has the side-effect of deleting own array elements whose array index is between the old and new length values.

Also, [ArraySetLength](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-arraysetlength) is specifying that a `Delete` is performed for `whose numeric value is greater than or equal to newLen, in descending numeric index order`

So no - there will be no memory leak if you reduce the length of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[]` or `new Array(10000)` will both create Arrays with exactly the same memory footprint. Just the length has a different initial value.

JavaScript is different from other languages, where an array of size n will have n storage spaces reserved for the elements.

Answer (score 0):

if array length is set to smaller value then other values gets removed/deleted from the array.

lets say

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
```

then if you set

```
arr.length = 1;
```

then the `arr` will have only `[1]`, other elements gets removed from the array.