# Modifying a copy of an array is NOT causing the original object to change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class where I manage some arrays, they get filled with data that I get from an API I consume. These lists represent clients by state, depending on their status I store these clients in their corresponding list. For privacy reasons I cannot share the entire code with you, but I can extract some things to help you understand my problem.

Let's assume the following where I initialize said arrays like this:

```js
   this.waitingClientsList = [];
   this.usersAttendedList = [];
   this.absentClientsList = [];
   this.suspendedClientsList = [];
   this.announcedClientsList = [];
   this.clientsBatch = [];
```

Each list will start empty.

To avoid repeating too much code, I manage them with a dictionary like this:

```js
   this.listsByState = {
      "waiting": this.waitingClientsList,
      "suspended": this.suspendedClientsList,
      "absent": this.absentClientsList,
      "inattention": this.usersAttendedList,
      "invideocall": this.usersAttendedList,
      "announced": this.announcedClientsList,
      "vdconnectingerror": this.usersAttendedList,
      "videocallended": this.usersAttendedList,
      "vdmissedcall": this.usersAttendedList
    }
```

To update their content I have a function that checks an API method that works with pagination, retrieves the data and stores it in their respective list like this (this is an example):

```js
private GetWaitingClients(state, nextPage, id, pageSize?, pageNumber?) {
    this._requestService.getWaitingClients(state, id, pageSize, pageNumber).then(async (response: any[]) => {
      // Getting the list by state
      let clientList = this.listsByState[state];
      // if we are changing the page, we should empty the respective list
      if (nextPage) {
          clientList = [];
      }

      response.map(item => {
        // If the client doesn't exist, it pushes it to the list
        // otherwise I manipulate the client
        if (clientList.some(obj => obj.virtualSpaceId == item.virtualSpaceId)) {
          // I do something here if the client exists
        } else {
          // If not, I push it to the list
          clientList.push(item);
        }
      });

      [...]
      // More stuff that I do
    }).catch(error => {
      // Here I print the error in case there was a problem with the API request
    });
  }
```

I retrieve each list with this line of code `let clientList = this.listsByState[state];`, this is the way I found to avoid doing a switch/case statement or multiple if/else statements. So far, this works fine. If there's a new entry in the database, both the local variable `clientList` and their referenced array update correspondingly, no problems there.

I have the method in the API built in a way that the first time the page loads it will return the first page with 5 results. If I change the page on the front-end, the function kicks in and should retrieve the next 5 results, so on so forth.

The problem is that when I change the page the variable `clientList` does get updated if I change its content **but the original referenced array does not**, which is bugging me. As far as I understand, when doing this assignment `let clientList = this.listsByState[state];` I assume that `clientList` is pointing to the same object that its corresponding list in memory but that's not happening here so I don't know where is my problem. I also tried emptying the `clientList` variable before doing the `map` operation but it does nothing, the original array remains unchanged.

The only way I can manage to change the referenced array content is by doing a direct assignment like this, for example: `this.waitingClientsList = clientList`, but this invalidates my previous code and that lefts me with no choice but to do a big and ugly switch/case statement or multiple if/else statements which I don't want to do. I'm trying to keep my code as clean as possible.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not understanding why tou are using async/await and .then() togheter. Never seen before...I don't know if it solve but use only one! [I will edit the code]

Comment: @NiccolòBiagi thanks for the suggestion but no, it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway, I'll keep waiting for the correct answer.

Comment: "_the variable clientList does get updated if I change its content but the original referenced array does not_": how do you change the content of `clientList` when this happens? It seems to me that it is missing from your code sample, whereas it is very probably the culprit. Same for "_I also tried emptying the clientList variable_": what exact code do you use to empty the variable?

Comment: I agree with @ghybs

Comment: @ghybs I've added the piece of code that I was missing regarding emptying the ```clientList``` variable, I do ```clientList = []```. Related to the second question: whenever the ```GetWaitingClients``` function executes and after I fetch the data from the API, I use the ```map``` function on the ```response``` variable, inside that function I'm trying to manipulate the ```clientList``` variable's content. Check that I do this first: ```let clientList = this.listsByState[state];```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // Getting the list by state
  let clientList = this.listsByState[state];
  // if we are changing the page, we should empty the respective list
  if (nextPage) {
      clientList = [];
  }
```

Are you expecting this line of code to also reset the array for this.listsByStatep[state]? It won't do that as you've assigned a new array to clientList and so the reference isn't the same (you can check this by doing `console.log(clientList === this.listsByStatep[state])` before and after you assign the []). To do what you're looking for change it to this:

```
  // Getting the list by state
  let clientList = this.listsByState[state];
  // if we are changing the page, we should empty the respective list
  if (nextPage) {
      clientList.length = 0;
  }
```

This doesn't destroy the reference and empties the array.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's true that is not the same before and after assigning ```[]```, I confirmed that with your example, but it doesn't solve my problem either. In fact, I do want the reference to change, that's why I did ```let clientList = this.listsByState[state];```, this ```listsByState``` variable stores references to the lists that I want to manipulate and just for simplicity and to avoid code repetition I manage them in that way, maybe is not the best way but it helped me to keep the code clean.

Comment: Another interesting thing is: I tried the ```clientList.length = 0``` approach and if I do ```console.log(this.waitingClientsList === this.listsByState[virtualSpaceStateValue]);``` before and after doing ```clientList.length = 0``` to the variable the log always return true. So even knowing that ```clientList``` in theory should have a reference to the original array, the original doesn't change at all..

Answer (score 2):

First thanks both [@ghybs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108796/ghybs) and [@Mathew Breg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973651/mathew-berg) for the suggestions.

First, I removed the `clientList = []` assignment and I used `clientList.length = 0` instead which works perfectly as both of you pointed out. [I've found another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript) where it states that `clientList = []` is, actually, the fastest way to empty an array **if you don't have references to the original one**, otherwise the original will remain unchanged. That was my first mistake.

The second mistake is (and it's also something I didn't mention before and it needs a rework) that I currently have a `subscription` to a service that controls the page visibility that I was not handling correctly. Every time my page gained focus the original array will be populated entirely, and it would be shown as unchanged. Once I commented that piece of code and in conjunction with `clientList.length = 0` and some corrections here and there, everything started to work flawlessly.

Another thing I've added to the code that helped me to refresh the table view (a thing to mention I forgot => to display the results, I'm currently using [`MatTable`](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) and [`MatPaginator`](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview) for the data pagination from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/)) is the `renderRows()` function from the `MatTable` I use to display the data on the page after I change the page index.

I would love to mark both comments as the answers to my question because despite this simple line of code `clientList.length = 0` was the correct way to manipulate the original array reference, the problem was somewhere else in my code after doing some more tests and debugs. For now, I'll mark the answer from [@Mathew Breg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973651/mathew-berg) but I want you to know that both of you were correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is a classic JS mistake:

- assign the reference to an object into a new variable (typically to shorten the code) `var short = myObject.some.long.path.or[dynamicKey]`
- make a deep change => the original object is correctly modified `short.subProperty = 2; myObject.some.long.path.or[dynamicKey].subProperty === 2;`
- re-assign the variable and expect the original object to be modified accordingly => disappointment :-( `short = null; myObject.some.long.path.or[dynamicKey].subProperty === 2;`

(In the example I used an object, but it is the same for an array)

In your case, since your `test` dynamic key is always in scope, you can simply keep on using it whenever you want to access the corresponding list: `this.listsByState[state] = [];`

Yes it may look redundant / less readable, but you now have a working code at least.

Now to correctly use your new `clientList` variable and keep on modifying the original list, as shown above and implied by MathewBerg's answer, simply make sure to *always* use a deep property or function that *mutates the object in place*:

```
clientList.length = 0; // works
clientList.splice(0, clientList.length); // to empty

clientList.push("itemAtTheEnd"); // works
clientList.unshift("itemAtTheStart"); // works
clientList.splice(2, 0, "insertedItem"); // to insert after the 2nd item

clientList.pop();
clientList.shift();
clientList.splice(3, 1); // to remove the 3rd item
```

You can easily enforce this rule in your code by preventing re-assignment:

```
// Initialize a const variable to forbid re-assignment
const clientList = this.listsByState[state];
```