# How to reset reactive array in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have an array `plan` defined using [store state management](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api) as follows:

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export const store = reactive({
    plan: []
})
```

I want to reset this array before filling it again, I have tried:

```js
import { store } from "./store.js";
store.plan = [];
store.plan = newPlan; // store.plan is accumulated here without reset!
```

Can you please tell me how can I reset this reactive array before assigning the new array to it?

Comment: Accumulated? Are you sure newPlan does not contain more than you think?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Yes, I'm sure, I have investigated the values using `console.log()` before and after.

Comment: Did you tried to clear it with like `store.plan.splice(0, store.plan.length)` ?

Comment: @Elikill58 I tried your solution, and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are creating a new instance for the array. As the objective of `reactive` function is to share the same instance, it keeps the old array.

You should edit the array instance by [cleaning it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/10952503) like that:

```js
store.plan.splice(0, store.plan.length)
```

You can also use `store.plan.length = 0`.