# Java: Simplest way to get last word in a string

Tags: java, string

What is the simplest way to get the last word of a string in Java?  You can assume no punctuation (just alphabetic characters and whitespace).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181969/java-get-last-element-after-split

Comment: Title says "fastest", questions asks for "simplest". Please clarify.

Comment: Fastest and simplest for coding and reading.  Execution time is irrelevant.  As an aside, having different wording is better for search purposes although the discrepancy was unintentional.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

```
String test =  "This is a sentence";
String lastWord = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```

Comment: Needs a +1 there and fails on a single word.

Comment: One line is nice since I will be using it in Velocity template code.  Could be combined with a regular expession to account for other characters like JST's solution.

Comment: Actually this is better, it already accounts for a single word:
String lastWord = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);

Comment: what if a sentence has some punctuation at the end?
"This is a sentence?!"

Answer (score 22):

```
String testString = "This is a sentence";
String[] parts = testString.split(" ");
String lastWord = parts[parts.length - 1];
System.out.println(lastWord); // "sentence"
```

Comment: This is the solution I probably would have come up with on my own, not bad, but a one-liner would be better.

Comment: When you say "fastest," do you mean shortest in code or fastest to execute?  This could be made into a one liner, but it wouldn't execute any faster and would be much harder to read.

Comment: I did not say "fastest", I said "simplest", by which I meant a combination of brevity and ease of understanding.

Comment: @Muhd If it were me, I would think the above is easiest to read.  Then again, this is also the solution I immediately came up with.  @OscarRyz's solution is also simple to read, so it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @Dave Probably mine, is not easier to read anymore for I have added a check in case the string it self is the last word.

Comment: Yeah, now Dave's is easiest to read, although one can cure hard to read code with a quick comment.

Comment: Umm parts.length() should not have the parentheses.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a way to do it using `String`'s built-in regex capabilities:

```
String lastWord = sentence.replaceAll("^.*?(\\w+)\\W*$", "$1");
```

The idea is to match the whole string from `^` to `$`, capture the last sequence of `\w+` in a capturing group 1, and replace the whole sentence with it using `$1`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/27jyQq)

Comment: This one is solid gold

Comment: Neat because it's a one liner

Comment: Edge case: This fails in right-to-left languages (ex. Hebrew).  @OscarRyz substring method still works. https://ideone.com/MacH0s

Answer (score 12):

If other whitespace characters are possible, then you'd want:

```
testString.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) (from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)). It avoids index-magic, so it's easier to understand. Unfortunately [`substringAfterLast`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfterLast%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) returns empty string when there is no separator in the input string so we need the `if` statement for that case.

```
public static String getLastWord(String input) {
    String wordSeparator = " ";
    boolean inputIsOnlyOneWord = !StringUtils.contains(input, wordSeparator);
    if (inputIsOnlyOneWord) {
        return input;
    }
    return StringUtils.substringAfterLast(input, wordSeparator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the last word in Kotlin:

```
String.substringAfterLast(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String s="print last word";
    x:for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
         if(s.charAt(i)==' ') {
                for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++) {
                    System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
                }
                break x;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).