# How to split String before first comma?

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I have an overriding method with String which returns String in format of:

```
 "abc,cde,def,fgh"
```

I want to split the string content into two parts:

1. String before first comma and
2. String after first comma

My overriding method is :

```java
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {

    placeTitle.setText(addressText);
}
```

Now how do I split the string into two parts, so that I can use them to set the text in two different `TextView`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You may use the following code snippet

```
String str ="abc,cde,def,fgh";
String kept = str.substring( 0, str.indexOf(","));
String remainder = str.substring(str.indexOf(",")+1, str.length());
```

Comment: I feel this is the best answer since you can have it in one line. Thank you

Comment: but if it doesen't find any comma then it will crash as error -----java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Answer (score 11):

```
String splitted[] =s.split(",",2); // will be matched 1 times. 

splitted[0]  //before the first comma. `abc`
splitted[1]  //the whole String after the first comma. `cde,def,fgh`
```

If you want only `cde` as the string after first comma.
Then you can use

```
String splitted[] =s.split(",",3); // will be matched  2 times
```

or without the limit

```
String splitted[] =s.split(",");
```

Don't forget to check the `length` to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`.

Comment: splitted[1] will not return the full string after the first comma

Comment: OP says :`2) string after first comma` what does  it mean ?  and if there is input like ` abc,cde,def,fgh` then  i see `splitted[1] ` will return `cde` isn't it? @Arjit

Comment: No @saif you are wrong. _splitted[1]_ will have cde and Op wants to have _cde,def,fgh_ Also hope you read this in question **I want to split the string Content into two parts**

Comment: The method split(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char)

Comment: Probably it is a typo. String has not any overloaded version of `split()` method for `char`. Use s.split(",") instead.

Answer (score 3):

The below is what you are searching for:

```
public String[] split(",", 2)
```

This will give 2 string array. Split has [two versions.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_split_limit.htm) What you can try is

```
String str = "abc,def,ghi,jkl";
String [] twoStringArray= str.split(",", 2); //the main line
System.out.println("String befor comma = "+twoStringArray[0]);//abc
System.out.println("String after comma = "+twoStringArray[1]);//def,ghi,jkl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 String s =" abc,cde,def,fgh";
 System.out.println("subString1="+ s.substring(0, s.indexOf(",")));
 System.out.println("subString2="+ s.substring(s.indexOf(",") + 1, s.length()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Note the use of limit to prevent it from splitting into more than 2 parts
String [] parts = s.split(",", 2);

// ...setText(parts[0]);
// ...setText(parts[1]);
```

For more information, refer to this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Answer (score 1):

Use split with regex:

```
String splitted[] = addressText.split(",",2);
System.out.println(splitted[0]);
System.out.println(splitted[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From <sup>[*`jse1.4`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/enhancements.html#jdk1.4)</sup>`String` - *Two `split` methods are new. The subSequence method has been added, as required by the CharSequence interface that String now implements. Three additional methods have been added: `matches`, `replaceAll`, and `replaceFirst`.*

Using Java [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) with [`Pattern.quote(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these parameters:
>
> ```
>   Regex     Limit          Result
>     :         2       { "boo", "and:foo" }
>     :         5       { "boo", "and", "foo" }
>     :        -2       { "boo", "and", "foo" }
>     o         5       { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
>     o        -2       { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
>     o         0       { "b", "", ":and:f" }
> ```

```java
String str = "abc?def,ghi?jkl,mno,pqr?stu,vwx?yz";
String quotedText = Pattern.quote( "?" );
// ? - \\? we have to escape sequence of some characters, to avoid use Pattern.quote( "?" );
String[] split = str.split(quotedText, 2); // ["abc", "def,ghi?jkl,mno,pqr?stu,vwx?yz"]
for (String string : split) {
    System.out.println( string );
}
```

I have face the same problem in URL parameters, To resoleve it i need to split based on first `?` So that the remaing String contains parameter values and they need to be split based on `&`.

```java
String paramUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=encode+url&oq=encode+url";

String subURL = URLEncoder.encode( paramUrl, "UTF-8");
String myMainUrl = "http://example.com/index.html?url=" + subURL +"&name=chrome&version=56";

System.out.println("Main URL : "+ myMainUrl );

String decodeMainURL = URLDecoder.decode(myMainUrl, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("Main URL : "+ decodeMainURL );

String[] split = decodeMainURL.split(Pattern.quote( "?" ), 2);

String[] Parameters = split[1].split("&");
for (String param : Parameters) {
    System.out.println( param );
}
```

---

[Run Javascript on the JVM with Rhino/Nashorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49171551/5081877) « With JavaScript’s [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function:

```js
var str = "abc?def,ghi?jkl,mno,pqr?stu,vwx?yz";
var parts = str.split(',');
console.log( parts ); // (5) ["abc?def", "ghi?jkl", "mno", "pqr?stu", "vwx?yz"]
console.log( str.split('?') ); // (5) ["abc", "def,ghi", "jkl,mno,pqr", "stu,vwx", "yz"]

var twoparts = str.split(/,(.+)/);
console.log( parts ); // (3) ["abc?def", "ghi?jkl,mno,pqr?stu,vwx?yz", ""]
console.log( str.split(/\?(.+)/) ); // (3) ["abc", "def,ghi?jkl,mno,pqr?stu,vwx?yz", ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

:In this case you can use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with some regex to get this input so you can use :

```
 System.out.println("test another :::"+test.replaceAll("(\\.*?),.*", "$1"));
```

If the key is just an **String** you can use `(\\D?),.*`

```
System.out.println("test ::::"+test.replaceAll("(\\D?),.*", "$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] **stringToInt**(String inp,int n)
{
**int a[]=new int[n];**
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(inp.indexOf(",")==-1)
    {
        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(inp);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(inp.substring(0, inp.indexOf(",")));
        inp=inp.substring(inp.indexOf(",")+1,inp.length());
    }
}
return a;
}
```

I created this function. Arguments are **input string** **(String inp, here)** and **integer value(int n, here)**, which is the size of an array which contains values in string separated by commas. You can use other special character to extract values from string containing that character. This function will return array of integer of size n.

**To use**,

```
String inp1="444,55";
int values[]=stringToInt(inp1,2);
```